# How to implement endless list with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, material-design, onscrolllistener

I would like to change `ListView` to [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). I want to use the `onScroll` of the [`OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll) in `RecyclerView` to determine if a user scrolled to the end of the list.

How do I know if a user scrolls to the end of the list so that I can fetch new data from a REST service?

Comment: Please check this link It will help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293461/using-onscroll-in-android-listview/26293762#26293762

Comment: **Please read the question carefully!** I know how to do this with a ListView but NOT how to implement it with a [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Comment: how to implement loadmore onscrolllistener in android.data is loaded but updated on existing data please help me

Comment: You can use this library: https://github.com/rockerhieu/rv-adapter-endless/. It is based on the idea of  `cwac-endless` for `ListView`.

Comment: https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate

Comment: am not using any libreary.just coordinatorlayout with in nested scrollview on it recycelrview please help me

Comment: private final RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final int newState) {
            // code
            Log.i("onScrollStateChanged called","called");
            currentScrollState = newState;
         //   if (currentVisibleItemCount >0) {
                Log.i("onScrollStateChanged called 1","called");
                if (!isLoading) {

Comment: plse help me:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efe45ab281ce9bd66a6990960f45708f

Answer (score 473, accepted):

Thanks to @Kushal and this is how I implemented it

```
private boolean loading = true;
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (dy > 0) { //check for scroll down
            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    loading = false;
                    Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                    // Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data

                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: This `OnScrollListener` works well, but how do you handle adding and removing a "load more" view in the `RecyclerView`?  I don't have any custom ItemAnimator set on the `RecyclerView`, but when I add and remove a "load more" view, the other items in a StaggeredGrid fly into or out of position in a strange manner.

Comment: What can i do for `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

Comment: What about `mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==mLayoutManager.getItemCount()-1`

Comment: what about for normal gridview

Comment: To all who `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` not resolved you should change `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` to `LinearLayoutManager `

Comment: @PratikButani if you use `LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItem()` instead of its `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` equivalent it should be good

Comment: setOnScrollListener is deprecated --> use addOnScrollListener and removeOnSrollListener instead

Comment: How to do this for StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Comment: Thanks.. For this code..I was also not getting  findFirstVisibleItemPosition(), i changed to Recyclerview's  to LinearLayoutManager ..It Worked....

Comment: Keep in mind that it's probably a good idea to start loading in new values before (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount, because this is the bottom of the list. If you wait until this check to add new values, your users will notice they'll hit a "wall", and then, after new values are loaded, they can continue scrolling.

Comment: If you can't access mentioned methods, please think about up-casting in ```onScrolled()```.
```LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();```

Comment: `setOnScrollListener` is deprecated so now use `addOnScrollListener`

Comment: @laaptu  `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` returns -1 when recyclerView items are bigger than screen, so i think better to use `findLastVisibleItemPosition`

Comment: For future viewers: Kushal Sharma's answer is more precise and easier to use.

Comment: where is the condition for making `loading = true` again?

Comment: A better approach includes the scroll velocity. If the user scrolls through large lists quickly, you'll hit the bottom of the list quickly and in many cases that is too short of time to retrieve more data from a source like a server and format it to be included in the list. The user will see this delay.

Comment: Is there an interface for RecyclerView's Scroll

Comment: Just want to know... I saw many people using `visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems >= totalItemCount `, isn't `findLastVisibleItemPosition() ` more straight forward? `if (!loading && (mLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == totalItemCount - 1))`, is there any wrong using this ?

Comment: Don't forget to add `loading = true` after `//Do pagination` part. otherwise this code will run only once and you can't load more item.

Comment: for `StaggeredGridLayout` , set `pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null)[0]` . where mLayoutManager is an instance of StaggeredGridLayoutManager . From [paginate](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate)

Comment: How can I know if I on the first Item ?

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to set loading to true when loading data (false when finished) and check if(!loading) before loading?

Comment: the variables firstVisibleItem , visibleItemCount, totalItemCount are declared outside the inner class and i get an error like you cannot use these in the scroll listener unless they are final ??

Comment: For those who are using StaggeredGridLayoutManager, please check this link it will be helpfull : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463560/findfirstvisibleitempositions-doesnt-work-for-recycleview-android/45768855#45768855

Comment: Hello there,its worked perfectly but while scrolling some data is changing.what i have to do

Comment: https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Pagination-with-RecyclerView/tree/a1dd15095bdfc48fd41171061d1226963e07c0f8

Comment: This one only load more data one time, after the first load it won't load more data even if you reaches to the bottom.

Comment: The problem with this solution is once you scroll all the way to bottom to fetch data, and you slightly scroll it up and downwards it makes the query multiple times

Comment: Sometimes it works properly, after a few more times it does not work properly

Comment: `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` doesn't exist for me on `LinearLayoutManager`

Answer (score 177):

Make these variables.

```
private int previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = true;
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
```

Set on Scroll for recycler view.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) 
            <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            Log.i("Yaeye!", "end called");

            // Do something

            loading = true;
        }
    }
});
```

> **Note :** Make sure you are using `LinearLayoutManager` as layout manager for `RecyclerView`.

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and for a grid

```
GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), spanCount);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Have fun with your endless scrolls !! ^.^

> **Update :** mRecyclerView.<s>setOnScrollListener()</s> is deprecated just replace with `mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener()` and the warning will be gone! You can read more from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971917/android-setonscrolllistner-on-recyclerview-deprecated).

**Since Android now officially support Kotlin, here is an update for the same -**

Make OnScrollListener

```
class OnScrollListener(val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager, val adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>, val dataList: MutableList<Int>) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    var previousTotal = 0
    var loading = true
    val visibleThreshold = 10
    var firstVisibleItem = 0
    var visibleItemCount = 0
    var totalItemCount = 0

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.childCount
        totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
        firstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false
                previousTotal = totalItemCount
            }
        }

        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            val initialSize = dataList.size
            updateDataList(dataList)
            val updatedSize = dataList.size
            recyclerView.post { adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(initialSize, updatedSize) }
            loading = true
        }
    }
}
```

and add it to your RecyclerView like this

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener(layoutManager, adapter, dataList))
```

For a full code example, feel free to refer [this Github repo](https://github.com/kushalsharma/kotlin-example).

Comment: Any idea of how to apply this solution with a GridLayoutManager? Since the `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` method is only available with the LinearLayoutManager, I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Additional information: in this case, using `visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();` behaves the same as using `visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();`.

Comment: Place the code in onScrollStateChanged() method instead of onScrolled() method.

Comment: What about with a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` since the `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` method is not available?

Comment: @toobsco42 You can use this : `int[] firstVisibleItemPositions = new int[yourNumberOfColumns];
pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItemPositions)[0];`

Comment: add findLastVisibleItemPosition or findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition and this is the perfect anwer imo.
No need for calculations!

Comment: What is this findFirstVisibleItemPosition() not resolved

Comment: To all those who are getting "findFirstVisibleItemPosition() not resolved" please use LinearLayoutManager instead of just LinearLayout. Here is the documentation link -  [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition())

Comment: This does not behave correctly when you try to refresh again and again with swipe refresh

Comment: I don't see a difference when changing the parameter `visibleThreshold`, can someone explain its meaning?

Comment: a little simpler approach

`if ( !loading && (totalItemCount) <= ( lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold )) {
                    loadMore( totalItemCount/itemsPerPage + 1 );
                    loading = true;
                }`

Comment: Just want to know... Isn't `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` more straight forward? `if (!loading && (mLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == totalItemCount - 1))`, is there any wrong using this ?

Comment: @BeeingJk the idea here is that I want to do a long operation in background (like making a network request for data of query DB for more data etc) as soon as the end of list is reached and thus lazy load stuff only when required. Since I already made a request for more data and IF the user scrolls back up and comes back down the logic without holding a state will trigger another request to get the data. So with `loading` variable we make sure we reach the end of list only once. If we get a error callback while getting the data, you can set the `loading` flag to `false` & hence trigger it again

Comment: @KushalSharma thanks for your explaination. I'm just curious about the different of `if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) 
            <= (firstVisibleItem))` and 'if (!loading && (mLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == totalItemCount - 1))' , because I saw many people are using the first one with "this minus that" instead of calling the existing `findLastVisibleItemPosition()`

Comment: What is the purpose of `visibleThreshold` here?

Comment: am also fallowing your answer,in my fragment am plan to show recyclerview data using pagenations.for that oncreateview am calling async task with page=1,and then recyclerview.addOnScroll increase the page count and once again call async task only first time data is replaced with second time and then not called the addonscroll please help me

Comment: where i need to call recyclerview.addonscrolllistener after first loading data to recycelrview

Comment: but scrollstatechanged called every time onscroll onli first time please give prorper solution.where i code onscroll or onscrollstatechanged,

Comment: please am posting code:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efe45ab281ce9bd66a6990960f45708f

Comment: getWebServiceData();  mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
 public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
   {
    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
 pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    if (loading) {if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
 loading = false;
 Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
  getWebServiceData();
 }} }  }});

Comment: oneafter one calling asynctask and addonscroll also with out scroll recycelrview only called please

Comment: @ShaishavJogani, the purpose of the visible threshold (I believe) is to begin querying the next set of items before the user hits the bottom of the RecyclerView. A good conceptual explanation can be found [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView)

Comment: second time when I scroll down, it is not recognising..why so?

Comment: @KushalSharma This code loads more data immediately I open the app. What I need to assign to `previousTotal` and `visibleThreshold`? I don't get it. I would like to load more data when there is only 3 items below.

Answer (score 79):

For those who only want to get notified when the last item is totally shown, you can use `View.canScrollVertically()`.

Here is my implementation:

```
public abstract class OnVerticalScrollListener
        extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    @Override
    public final void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
            onScrolledToTop();
        } else if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            onScrolledToBottom();
        } else if (dy < 0) {
            onScrolledUp();
        } else if (dy > 0) {
            onScrolledDown();
        }
    }

    public void onScrolledUp() {}

    public void onScrolledDown() {}

    public void onScrolledToTop() {}

    public void onScrolledToBottom() {}
}
```

Note: You can use `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().canScrollVertically()` if you want to support API < 14.

Comment: This is a great and simple answer! Thank you!

Comment: A similar solution can be used for pull to refresh by checking !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1).

Comment: Best solution out there. Thanks dude!

Comment: @LordParsley Thank you, updated. This is also one of the way SwipeRefreshLayout checks for pull to refresh.

Comment: Cool. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: This is great, but it's API Level 14+. Hopefully you won't be as unlucky as I am.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce If you are using `RecyclerView` you'll be lucky again, because you can simply make a static copy of `View.canScrollVertically()` since the related methods are marked public instead of protected in `RecyclerView`. You can also extend `RecyclerView` to re-implement `canScrollVertically()` if you like. A third and simple way is to call `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().canScrollVertically()`. Edited in my answer.

Comment: onScrolled is never called if the list is too small.

Comment: This isn't that useful for endless/infinite scrolling since once onScrolledToBottom() has been called it's already too late for the last visible item to be modified before the user reaches the end of the list, as a result the user has to perform an additional scrolling action to reveal the progress indicator. Far from smooth.

Comment: Thanks @Dreaming in Code  Your answer helped me. One more thing i was using match_parent height of recyler view , thats why it was getting called again and again.

Answer (score 75):

Here is another approach. It will work with any layout manager.

1. Make Adapter class abstract
2. Then create an abstract method in adapter class (eg. load())
3. In **onBindViewHolder** check the position if last and call load()
4. Override the load() function while creating the adapter object in your activity or fragment.
5. In the overided load function implement your loadmore call

For a detail understanding I wrote a blog post and example project get it here
http://sab99r.com/blog/recyclerview-endless-load-more/

MyAdapter.java

```
public abstract class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            //check for last item
            if ((position >= getItemCount() - 1))
                load();
        }

        public abstract void load();
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Items> items;
    MyAdapter adapter;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    adapter=new MyAdapter(items){
            @Override
            public void load() {
                //implement your load more here
                Item lastItem=items.get(items.size()-1);
                loadMore();
            }
        };
   }
}
```

Comment: Like the solution, you don't have to make your adapter abstract, instead you can create an interface in your adapter and make your activity implement it keeping it flexible and elegant, ex: ItemDisplayListener=>onItemDisplayed(int position). This way you can load at any position: at N, N-1, N-2..

Comment: I like this solution !! No need to listen to all scroll events and to make potentially costly computations

Comment: This will endlessy call load() if the last item is visible and no more items will be loaded by loadMore() (e. g., we reached the end of the *source* list as well). Do you have a solution for this situation?

Comment: @mcwise add a boolean finished=false; when you reach the end make finished=true.. change the current if condition to if ((position >= getItemCount() - 1) && (!finished))

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. This is elegant and simple.

Comment: A good example of the superior solution buried under the popularity of the first solution.  Very often, the last row will be bound to a separate viewtype which serves as a "Loading..." banner.  When this viewtype gets a bind call, it will set up a callback which triggers a data change notification when more data is available.  The accepted answer of hooking up the scroll listener is wasteful, and probably doesn't work for other layout types.

Comment: I generally prefer this kind of solution, in part because it's possible that the first bunch of data won't fill the entire screen for whatever reason and you'd still want to keep loading data without making the user do a pointless scroll.

Comment: @mcwise it'd only endlessly call if the user actively scrolls away and back to the last item. onBindViewHolder is only called once each time the view enters the screen and would not constantly call it.

Comment: I also like this solution, but it has one major problem. When you use some loading view as item of list, you can't just simply call notifyItemChanged. And yeah as @mcwise says, it could be infinite loading loop in wrong hands. But double mutex could solve it 
`if(!loading)if(!loading){loading = true: load()}`

Comment: @l0v3 I just posted the method to implement the load more functionality... to add loading view add recycleView.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //loadMore();
                        }
                    }); in the load() function.. which will fix the recycleview onscroll notifydatasetchange issue

Comment: simplicity is definitely here, but what about performance, is it approach more efficient than the others?

Comment: @SabeerMohammed you should create a github repository to display the full use of your code. It will be very helpful to all users

Comment: You should add a kotlin version

Comment: if you need to call `notifydatasetchanged` to refresh your UI after loading more items, be sure to make your call in `recyclerView.post(new Runnable())` otherwise you get an error as you can't update the data while scrolling. This makes sure it runs after the UI update is complete.

Answer (score 21):

My answer is a modified version of Noor. I passed from a `ListView` where i had `EndlessScrollListener` (that you can find easily in many answers on SO) to a `RecyclerView` so i wanted a `EndlessRecyclScrollListener` to easily update my past listener.

So here is the code, hope it helps:

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollRecyclListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
{
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;
    private int currentPage = 0;

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView mRecyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        super.onScrolled(mRecyclerView, dx, dy);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView
                .getLayoutManager();

        visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        onScroll(firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
    }

    public void onScroll(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount)
        {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0)
            {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }
        // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount))
        {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem +
                visibleThreshold))
        {
            onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

}
```

Comment: Your implementation requires the RecyclerView to use LinearLeayoutManager. Bad Idea!

Comment: @Orri Could you please explain why? Thanks!

Comment: In your onScrolled you cast the LayoutManager from the RecyclerView to LinearLayoutManager. Its not working for StaggredGridLayout or anthing else. There is not findFirstVisibleItemPosition() in StaggredGridLayout.

Answer (score 14):

For me, it's very simple:

```
     private boolean mLoading = false;

     mList.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int totalItem = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            int lastVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            if (!mLoading && lastVisibleItem == totalItem - 1) {
                mLoading = true;
                // Scrolled to bottom. Do something here.
                mLoading = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Be careful with asynchronous jobs: mLoading must be changed at the end of the asynchronous jobs. Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: I found this answer after days of questioning myself, basically. This is the best solution, imo.

Comment: please give some solution for recyclerview with loadmore page number passing android

Comment: getWebServiceData();

        mStoresAdapterData.setOnLoadMoreListener(new StoresAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                storesList.add(null);
                mStoresAdapterData.notifyItemInserted(storesList.size() - 1);
                ++pageNumber;
                getWebServiceData();
            }
        });  both calling one after another finally 2nd page data only visibled please help

Comment: i tried many implementation of the recyclerView pagination but none of them worked , except this one , you have my upvote sir

Answer (score 11):

With the power of Kotlin's extension functions, the code can look a lot more elegant. Put this anywhere you want (I have it inside an ExtensionFunctions.kt file):

```
/**
 * WARNING: This assumes the layout manager is a LinearLayoutManager
 */
fun RecyclerView.addOnScrolledToEnd(onScrolledToEnd: () -> Unit){

    this.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){

        private val VISIBLE_THRESHOLD = 5

        private var loading = true
        private var previousTotal = 0

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                                          newState: Int) {

            with(layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager){

                val visibleItemCount = childCount
                val totalItemCount = itemCount
                val firstVisibleItem = findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

                if (loading && totalItemCount > previousTotal){

                    loading = false
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount
                }

                if(!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)){

                    onScrolledToEnd()
                    loading = true
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
youRecyclerView.addOnScrolledToEnd {
    //What you want to do once the end is reached
}
```

This solution is based on Kushal Sharma's answer. However, this is a bit better because:

1. It uses `onScrollStateChanged` instead of `onScroll`. This is better because `onScroll` is called every time there is any sort of movement in the RecyclerView, whereas `onScrollStateChanged` is only called when the state of the RecyclerView is changed. Using `onScrollStateChanged` will save you CPU time and, as a consequence, battery.
2. Since this uses Extension Functions, this can be used in any RecyclerView you have. The client code is just 1 line.

Comment: When I did Pull `SwipeRefreshLayout's setOnRefreshListener the addOnScrolledToEnd is not working`


private inner class PullToRefresh : SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
        override fun onRefresh() {
            pbViewMore!!.visibility = View.GONE
            pageCount = 0
            courseList.clear()
            //calling asynctask here
            srlNoMessageRefreshLayout!!.isRefreshing = false
            swipeRefreshLayout!!.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

Comment: Hey Bitcoin Cash - ADA enthusiast, I've got a question. VISIBLE_THRESHOLD is the number of elements you want the recyclerList to show...right?...is it a limit?

Answer (score 9):

Most answer are assuming the `RecyclerView` uses a `LinearLayoutManager`, or `GridLayoutManager`, or even `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, or assuming that the scrolling is vertical or horyzontal, but **no one has posted a completly generic answer**.

Using the `ViewHolder`'s adapter is clearly not a good solution. An adapter might have more than 1 `RecyclerView` using it. It "adapts" their contents. It should be the Recycler**View** (which is the one class which is responsible of what is currently displayed to the user, and not the adapter which is responsible only to provide content to the `RecyclerView`) which must notify your *system* that more items are needed (to load).

Here is my solution, using nothing else than the abstracted classes of the RecyclerView (RecycerView.LayoutManager and RecycerView.Adapter):

```
/**
 * Listener to callback when the last item of the adpater is visible to the user.
 * It should then be the time to load more items.
 **/
public abstract class LastItemListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

      // init
      RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
      RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();

      if (layoutManager.getChildCount() > 0) {
        // Calculations..
        int indexOfLastItemViewVisible = layoutManager.getChildCount() -1;
        View lastItemViewVisible = layoutManager.getChildAt(indexOfLastItemViewVisible);
        int adapterPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(lastItemViewVisible);
        boolean isLastItemVisible = (adapterPosition == adapter.getItemCount() -1);

        // check
        if (isLastItemVisible)
          onLastItemVisible(); // callback
     }
   }

   /**
    * Here you should load more items because user is seeing the last item of the list.
    * Advice: you should add a bollean value to the class
    * so that the method {@link #onLastItemVisible()} will be triggered only once
    * and not every time the user touch the screen ;)
    **/
   public abstract void onLastItemVisible();

}


// --- Exemple of use ---

myRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new LastItemListener() {
    public void onLastItemVisible() {
         // start to load more items here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is right and it's worked for all `LayoutManagers` but only one moment: move your calculation code in another scrollListener method - move it to `onScrollStateChanged` instead  `onScrolled`. And in `onScrollStateChanged` just check: `if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) { // calculation code }`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I don't think it would be a better solution.
The developer wants its listener to be triggered even before the recyclerview stops to scroll. So it might finish to load new data items (if datas are stored localy), or even add a progress-bar view-holder at the end of the recyclerview, so when the recyclerview will stop to scroll, it can be on a circle progress-bar as last visible item.

Answer (score 8):

**This is how I do it, simple and short:**

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && dy != 0)
            {
                // Load more results here

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: how does this prevent flooding of more results request to the server? This reads like it will execute everytime the scroll view is scrolled, but quite often you only want to load more items when you get close to the bottom of the list.

Comment: @John-T One of the tremendous and working answer for my case. Thank you so much for this shortest answer.

Answer (score 7):

Although the accepted answer works perfectly, the solution below uses addOnScrollListener since setOnScrollListener is deprecated, and reduces number of variables, and if conditions.

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
feedsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

feedsRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (dy > 0) {   
            if ((layoutManager.getChildCount() + layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()) >= layoutManager.getItemCount()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "End of list");
                //loadMore();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sometimes my loadMore() method called thrice in onScrolled(), Any idea why it is called thrice and how to stop calling it multiple times.

Comment: dy>0 is always false

Comment: @ved That's because the scrolling has 3 states: scrolling, scrolled, idle. You pick one that's suitable.

Answer (score 6):

Although there are so many answers to the question, I would like to share our experience of creating the endless list view. We have recently implemented custom Carousel LayoutManager that can work in the cycle by scrolling the list infinitely as well as up to a certain point. Here is a [detailed description on GitHub](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager).

I suggest you take a look at this article with short but valuable recommendations on creating custom LayoutManagers: http://cases.azoft.com/create-custom-layoutmanager-android/

Answer (score 5):

OK, I did it by using the [onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) method of RecyclerView.Adapter.

**Adapter:**

```
public interface OnViewHolderListener {
    void onRequestedLastItem();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ...

    if (position == getItemCount() - 1) onViewHolderListener.onRequestedLastItem();
}
```

**Fragment** (or Activity)**:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_list, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    adapter = new Adapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...

    adapter.setOnViewHolderListener(new Adapter.OnViewHolderListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestedLastItem() {
            //TODO fetch new data from webservice
        }
    });
    return contentView;
}
```

Comment: relying on onBind is not a very good idea. RecyclerView does cache views + has some layout managers has means to pre-cache things.

I would suggest setting a scroll listener and when scroll listener stops, get the last visible item position from layout manager. If you are using default layout managers, they all have findLastVisible** methods.

Comment: @yigit

How far away will RecyclerView try to precache things? If you have 500 items, I really doubt it will cache so far away (otherwise it'll be just a giant waste of performance). When it'll actually start to cache (even when we at 480 element) that means it's time to load another batch anyway.

Comment: It doe snot preCache things unless it is smooth scrolling to a far away position. In that case, LLM (by default) layout out two pages instead of one so that it can find the target view and decelerate to it.

It does cache views that go out of bounds. By default, this cache size is 2 and can be configured via setItemCacheSize.

Comment: @yigit just thinking through the problem I dont see how caching could present an issue here; we are only interested in the first time the "last" items are bound anyway! Missing the call to onBindViewHolder when the layout manager re-uses a cached view that was already bound is just not an issue when we are interesting in paging in more data at the end of the list. Correct?

Comment: In my FlexibleAdapter library I chose to adopt the endless scroll with the call in `onBindViewHolder()`, it works like a charm. The implementation is tiny compared to the scroll listener and it's easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

```
 recyclerList.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx,int dy)
                {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy); 
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,int newState) 
                {
                    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    int lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (totalItemCount> 1) 
                    {
                        if (lastVisibleItem >= totalItemCount - 1) 
                        {
                            // End has been reached
                            // do something 
                        }
                    }          
                }
            });
```

Comment: `onScrollStateChanged()` will not work since it will be only called when you change the state of the scroll and not while you're scrolling. You must use the `onScrolled()` method.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to extend used `LayoutManager` (e.g. `LinearLayoutManager`) and override `scrollVerticallyBy()` method. Firstly, I would call `super` first and then check returned integer value. If the value equals to `0` then a bottom or a top border is reached. Then I would use `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` method to find out which border is reached and load more data if needed. Just an idea.

In addition, you can even return your value from that method allowing overscroll and showing "loading" indicator.

Answer (score 3):

I achieved an infinite scrolling type implementation using this logic in the `onBindViewHolder` method of my `RecyclerView.Adapter` class.

```
    if (position == mItems.size() - 1 && mCurrentPage <= mTotalPageCount) {
        if (mCurrentPage == mTotalPageCount) {
            mLoadImagesListener.noMorePages();
        } else {
            int newPage = mCurrentPage + 1;
            mLoadImagesListener.loadPage(newPage);
        }
    }
```

With this code when the RecyclerView gets to the last item, it increments the current page and callbacks on an interface which is responsible for loading more data from the api and adding the new results to the adapter.

I can post more complete example if this isn't clear?

Comment: I know this post is really old, but I'm somewhat of a newb and don't know what  where to get the variables you're comparing.
mCurrentPage and mTotalPageCount are refering to your data set I assume, and mItems is the arraylist of list items, but how do I find position?

Comment: You can see how I implemented my RecyclerView.Adapter here: https://github.com/dominicthomas/FlikrGridRecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/domji84/mcgridview/adapters/GridItemAdapter.java

Answer (score 3):

For people who use **StaggeredGridLayoutManager** here is my implementation, it works for me.

```
 private class ScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        firstVivisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVivisibleItems);

        if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && firstVivisibleItems[0]!=0) {
            loadMoreImages();
        }

    }

    private boolean loadMoreImages(){
        Log.d("myTag", "LAST-------HERE------");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SudheeshMohan
[Here](https://github.com/Dandewine/GoogleImageSearchAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dandewine/user/tocleveroad/fragments/ResultOfSearch.java) is full class, it's small)
In my project I change dynamically span count, and It will works for 1 and 2 span counts

Comment: recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) will do it but it requires API 14. :(

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy to use library for this named **paginate** . Supports both ListView and RecyclerView ( LinearLayout , GridLayout and StaggeredGridLayout).

Here is the [link](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate) to the project on Github

Answer (score 3):

My way to detect loading event is not to detect scrolling, but to listen whether the last view was attached. If the last view was attached, I regard it as timing to load more content.

```
class MyListener implements RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    MyListener(RecyclerView view) {
        mRecyclerView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mgr = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    int adapterPosition = mgr.getPosition(view);

    if (adapterPosition == adapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
        // last view was attached
        loadMoreContent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create an abstract class and extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

   ```
   public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
   private int previousTotal = 0;
   private boolean loading = true;
   private int visibleThreshold;
   private int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
   private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

   public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int visibleThreshold) {
   this.layoutManager = layoutManager; this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
   }
   @Override
   public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
   super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

   visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
   totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
   firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager)layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

   if (loading) {
       if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
           loading = false;
           previousTotal = totalItemCount;
       }
   }
   if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
       onLoadMore();
       loading = true;
   }
     }

   public abstract void onLoadMore();}
   ```
2. in activity (or fragment) add addOnScrollListener to recyclerView

   ```
   LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
   recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager, 3) {
       @Override
       public void onLoadMore() {
           //TODO
           ...
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

As @John T suggest. Just use code block below, really short, beauty and simple :D

```
public void loadMoreOnRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && dy != 0) {
                //Load more items here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can follow my Repo to understand the way that it work.

https://github.com/Nghien-Nghien/PokeAPI-Java/blob/0d8d69d348e068911b883f0ae7791d904cc75cb5/app/src/main/java/com/example/pokemonapi/MainActivity.java

Description info about app like this: https://github.com/skydoves/Pokedex#readme

Comment: Hi, If items are less than the screen size then it does not get called.

Answer (score 2):

I have a pretty detailed example of how to paginate with a RecyclerView.  At a high level, I have a set PAGE_SIZE , lets say 30.  So I request 30 items and if I get 30 back then I request the next page.  If I get less than 30 items I flag a variable to indicate that the last page has been reached and then I stop requesting for more pages.  Check it out and let me know what you think.

https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution using [AsyncListUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/AsyncListUtil.html), in the web says:
Note that this class uses a single thread to load the data, so it suitable to load data from secondary storage such as disk, but not from network. 
but i am using odata to read the data and work fine.
I miss in my example data entities and network methods.
I include only the example adapter.

```
public class AsyncPlatoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private final AsyncPlatoListUtil mAsyncListUtil;
    private final MainActivity mActivity;
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private final String mFilter;
    private final String mOrderby;
    private final String mExpand;

    public AsyncPlatoAdapter(String filter, String orderby, String expand, RecyclerView recyclerView, MainActivity activity) {
        mFilter = filter;
        mOrderby = orderby;
        mExpand = expand;
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mActivity = activity;
        mAsyncListUtil = new AsyncPlatoListUtil();

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.plato_cardview, parent, false);

        // Create a ViewHolder to find and hold these view references, and
        // register OnClick with the view holder:
        return new PlatoViewHolderAsync(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Plato item = mAsyncListUtil.getItem(position);
        PlatoViewHolderAsync vh = (PlatoViewHolderAsync) holder;
        if (item != null) {
            Integer imagen_id = item.Imagen_Id.get();
            vh.getBinding().setVariable(BR.plato, item);
            vh.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
            vh.getImage().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vh.getProgress().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String cacheName = null;
            String urlString = null;
            if (imagen_id != null) {
                cacheName = String.format("imagenes/imagen/%d", imagen_id);
                urlString = String.format("%s/menusapi/%s", MainActivity.ROOTPATH, cacheName);
            }
            ImageHelper.downloadBitmap(mActivity, vh.getImage(), vh.getProgress(), urlString, cacheName, position);
        } else {
            vh.getBinding().setVariable(BR.plato, item);
            vh.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
            //show progress while loading.
            vh.getImage().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            vh.getProgress().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAsyncListUtil.getItemCount();
    }

    public class AsyncPlatoListUtil extends AsyncListUtil<Plato> {
        /**
         * Creates an AsyncListUtil.
         */
        public AsyncPlatoListUtil() {
            super(Plato.class, //my data class
                    10, //page size
                    new DataCallback<Plato>() {
                        @Override
                        public int refreshData() {
                            //get count calling ../$count ... odata endpoint
                            return countPlatos(mFilter, mOrderby, mExpand, mActivity);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void fillData(Plato[] data, int startPosition, int itemCount) {
                            //get items from odata endpoint using $skip and $top
                            Platos p = loadPlatos(mFilter, mOrderby, mExpand, startPosition, itemCount, mActivity);
                            for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(itemCount, p.value.size()); i++) {
                                data[i] = p.value.get(i);
                            }

                        }
                    }, new ViewCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void getItemRangeInto(int[] outRange) {
                            //i use LinearLayoutManager in the RecyclerView
                            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                            outRange[0] = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                            outRange[1] = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDataRefresh() {
                            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemLoaded(int position) {
                            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(position);
                        }
                    });
            mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    onRangeChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 
 recyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
    //load more items.
 }
```

Fair and simple.
This will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `public void setOnScrollListener (RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener)` in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener%29. Use that

**EDIT:**

Override `onScrollStateChanged` method inside the `onScrollListener` and do this

```
            boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;

            //loading is used to see if its already loading, you have to manually manipulate this boolean variable
            if (loadMore && !loading) {
                 //end of list reached
            }
```

Comment: **Please be more specific!** How do I use [RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html) to determine that the user scrolled to the end of the list?

Comment: There is no onScroll at [RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html)! You mix the AbsListView.OnScrollListener with the RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.

Comment: ya it is supposed to be `onScrollStateChanged`

Comment: `onScrollStateChanged` will not work since it will be only called when you change the state of the scroll and not while you're scrolling.

Comment: @PedroOliveira Is it possible with `onScrollStateChanged` to determine that the user scrolls to the last item?

Comment: @erdna AFAIK no. You need to implement your own `RecyclerView` to report `onScroll` events.

Answer (score 1):

Check this every thing is explained in detail:
[Pagination using RecyclerView From A to Z](https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b#.70cvzo7cp)

```
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                     int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!mIsLoading && !mIsLastPage) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

loadMoreItems():

```
private void loadMoreItems() {
    mAdapter.removeLoading();
    //load data here from the server

    // in case of success
    mAdapter.addData(data);
    // if there might be more data
    mAdapter.addLoading();
}
```

in MyAdapter :

```
private boolean mIsLoadingFooterAdded = false;

public void addLoading() {
    if (!mIsLoadingFooterAdded) {
        mIsLoadingFooterAdded = true;
        mLineItemList.add(new LineItem());
        notifyItemInserted(mLineItemList.size() - 1);
    }
}

public void removeLoading() {
    if (mIsLoadingFooterAdded) {
        mIsLoadingFooterAdded = false;
        int position = mLineItemList.size() - 1;
        LineItem item = mLineItemList.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            mLineItemList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
}

public void addData(List<YourDataClass> data) {

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        YourDataClass yourDataObject = data.get(i);
        mLineItemList.add(new LineItem(yourDataObject));
        notifyItemInserted(mLineItemList.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The link may contain an answer, but try to explain some substantial parts of the explanations in the link in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I let you my aproximation. Works fine for me.

I hope it helps you.

```
/**
 * Created by Daniel Pardo Ligorred on 03/03/2016.
 */
public abstract class BaseScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public BaseScrollListener(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {

        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;

        this.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        this.onScroll(recyclerView, this.getFirstVisibleItem(), this.layoutManager.getChildCount(), this.layoutManager.getItemCount(), dx, dy);
    }

    private int getFirstVisibleItem(){

        if(this.layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager){

            return ((LinearLayoutManager) this.layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        } else if (this.layoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager){

            int[] spanPositions = null; //Should be null -> StaggeredGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions makes the work.

            try{

                return ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) this.layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPositions(spanPositions)[0];
            }catch (Exception ex){

                // Do stuff...
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public abstract void init();

    protected abstract void onScroll(RecyclerView recyclerView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount, int dx, int dy);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers take into account if the list is too small or not.

Here's a piece of code I've been using that works on RecycleViews in both directions.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (recyclerViewListener == null) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

        /**
         * If the list is too small to scroll.
         */
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (!canScrollVertically(1)) {
                recyclerViewListener.reachedBottom();
            } else if (!canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                recyclerViewListener.reachedTop();
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    public void setListener(RecyclerViewListener recycleViewListener) {
        this.recyclerViewListener = recycleViewListener;
        addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if (recyclerViewListener == null) {
                    return;
                }

                recyclerViewListener.scrolling(dy);

                if (!canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    recyclerViewListener.reachedBottom();
                } else if (!canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                    recyclerViewListener.reachedTop();
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@kushal @abdulaziz

Why not use this logic instead?

```
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    int totalItemCount, lastVisibleItemPosition;

    if (dy > 0) {
      totalItemCount = _layoutManager.getItemCount();
      lastVisibleItemPosition = _layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

      if (!_isLastItem) {
        if ((totalItemCount - 1) == lastVisibleItemPosition) {
          LogUtil.e("end_of_list");

          _isLastItem = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: My onScroller() called thrice for an single item so I get end_of_list thrice and my pagination logic called thrice. How to correct this to call pagination only once.

Comment: @ved That's not supposed to happen. That code above ensures the `end_of_list` condition will only be called once. The flag `_isLastItem` is a global variable in the activity that has a default value of `false`. What I did is to execute a background task after detecting the end of list, retrieving the next page then notify the adapter of the new dataset, and finally setting `_isLastItem` to false again.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager;

/**
 * Abstract Endless ScrollListener
 * 
 */
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener extends
        RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 10;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 1;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // The total number of items in the data set after the last load
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private int firstVisibleItem;
    private int visibleItemCount;
    private int totalItemCount;
    private LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public EndlessScrollListener(LayoutManager layoutManager) {
        validateLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold,
            LayoutManager layoutManager, int startPage) {
        validateLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }

    private void validateLayoutManager(LayoutManager layoutManager)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (null == layoutManager
                || !(layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager)
                || !(layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "LayoutManager must be of type GridLayoutManager or LinearLayoutManager.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        if (layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            firstVisibleItem = ((GridLayoutManager) layoutManager)
                    .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        } else if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager)
                    .findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading
                && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached do something
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have created LoadMoreRecyclerView using **Abdulaziz Noor Answer**

**LoadMoreRecyclerView**

```
public class LoadMoreRecyclerView extends RecyclerView  {

    private boolean loading = true;
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    //WrapperLinearLayout is for handling crash in RecyclerView
    private WrapperLinearLayout mLayoutManager;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public LoadMoreRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public LoadMoreRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    public LoadMoreRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        mLayoutManager = new WrapperLinearLayout(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        this.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        this.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        this.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(dx, dy);

        if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
        {
            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading)
            {
                if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount)
                {
                    loading = false;
                    Log.v("...", "Call Load More !");
                    if(onLoadMoreListener != null){
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(state);
    }

    public void onLoadMoreCompleted(){
        loading = true;
    }

    public void setMoreLoading(boolean moreLoading){
        loading = moreLoading;
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }
}
```

**WrapperLinearLayout**

```
public class WrapperLinearLayout extends LinearLayoutManager
{
    public WrapperLinearLayout(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        try {
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e("probe", "meet a IOOBE in RecyclerView");
        }
    }
}
```

//Add it in xml like

```
<your.package.LoadMoreRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</your.package.LoadMoreRecyclerView>
```

**OnCreate or onViewCreated**

```
mLoadMoreRecyclerView = (LoadMoreRecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mLoadMoreRecyclerView.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                callYourService(StartIndex);
            }
        });
```

**callYourService**

```
private void callYourService(){
    //callyour Service and get response in any List

    List<AnyModelClass> newDataFromServer = getDataFromServerService();
    //Enable Load More
    mLoadMoreRecyclerView.onLoadMoreCompleted();

    if(newDataFromServer != null && newDataFromServer.size() > 0){
            StartIndex += newDataFromServer.size();

            if (newDataFromServer.size() < Integer.valueOf(MAX_ROWS)) {
                    //StopLoading..
                   mLoadMoreRecyclerView.setMoreLoading(false);
            }
    }
    else{
            mLoadMoreRecyclerView.setMoreLoading(false);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to implement without the scroll listener, using the pure logic of the data model alone. The scroll view requires to get items by position as well as the maximal item count. The model can have the background logic to fetch the needed items in chunks, rather than one by one, and do this in the background thread, notifying the view when the data are ready.

This approach allows to have the fetching queue which prefers most recently requested (so currently visible) items over older (most likely already scrolled away) submissions, control the number of parallel threads to use and things the like. The complete source code for this approach (demo app and reusable library) are available [here](https://github.com/andviane/google-books-android-viewer).

Answer (score 1):

This solution works perfectly for me.

```
//Listener    

public abstract class InfiniteScrollListener     extendsRecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

public static String TAG = InfiniteScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
private int previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = true;
private int visibleThreshold = 1;
private int current_page = 1;

private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

public InfiniteScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount - firstVisibleItem <= visibleThreshold)) {

        current_page++;

        onLoadMore(current_page);

        loading = true;
    }
}

public void resetState() {
    loading = true;
    previousTotal = 0;
    current_page = 1;
}

public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}

//Implementation into fragment 
 private InfiniteScrollListener scrollListener;

scrollListener = new InfiniteScrollListener(manager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            //Load data
        }
    };
    rv.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rv.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

@erdna Please refer my below code.May be it will become helpful to you.

```
     int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
   recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.e("firstVisibleItem", firstVisibleItem + "");
            Log.e("visibleItemCount", visibleItemCount + "");
            Log.e("totalItemCount", totalItemCount + "");

            if (page != total_page_index) {
                if (loading) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem) >= totalItemCount) {
                        Log.e("page", String.valueOf(page));
                        page=page+1;
                        new GetSummary().execute(String.valueOf(page), "");
                        loading = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

No repetition calls however you scroll. fetchData will be called only when you are at the end of the list and there is more data to be fetched

Regarding my code:
1.fetchData() fetches 10 items on each call.
2.isScrolling is a class member variable
3.previousTotalCount is also a class member. It stores previously visited last item

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true
                }
            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

                val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
                val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
                val scrolledOutItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()


                if (isScrolling && (visibleItemCount + scrolledOutItems == totalItemCount)
                    && (visibleItemCount + scrolledOutItems != previousTotalCount)) {
                    previousTotalCount = totalItemCount              
                    isScrolling = false
                    fetchData()  //fetches 10 new items from Firestore
                    pagingProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this:

```
    final LinearLayoutManager rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvMovieList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMovieList);
    rvMovieList.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
    adapter = new MovieRecyclerAdapter(this, movies);
    rvMovieList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    rvMovieList.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        boolean loading = true;
        int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            visibleItemCount = rvLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = rvLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = rvLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            int lastitem = visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems;

            if ( lastitem == totalItemCount
                    && page < total_pages
                    && !keyword.equals("") ) {
                // hit bottom ..

                String strnext;
                if (page == total_pages - 1) {
                    int last = total_results - (page * 20);
                    strnext = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.next), last);
                } else {
                    strnext = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.next), 20);
                }
                btNext.setText(strnext);
                btNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                btNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if(pastVisiblesItems == 0 &&  page > 1){
                // hit top
                btPrev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                btPrev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

I've got confused where to put `loading` with `true` or `false`, so I try to remove it, and this code works as I expected.

Answer (score -1):

Here is example for Simple Implementation of **Endless Scrolling RecyclerView** using a Simple Library compiled from the various sources.

Add this line in `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.hereshem.lib:awesomelib:2.0.1'
```

Create RecyclerView Layout in Activity with

```
<com.hereshem.lib.recycler.MyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Create a ViewHolder by passing the class it supports

```
public static class EVHolder extends MyViewHolder<Events> {
    TextView date, title, summary;
    public EVHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        date = v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        summary = v.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(Events c) {
        date.setText(c.date);
        title.setText(c.title);
        summary.setText(c.summary);
    }
}
```

Create Items List variable and adapters with very few lines by passing items, class and layout in the adapter

```
List<Events> items = new ArrayList<>();
MyRecyclerView recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, items, EVHolder.class, R.layout.row_event);
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

ClickListener and LoadMore Listener can be added with following lines

```
recycler.setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recycler Item Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

recycler.setOnLoadMoreListener(new MyRecyclerView.OnLoadMoreListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore() {
        loadData();
    }
});
loadData();
```

After the data is loaded this must be called

```
recycler.loadComplete();
```

When no LoadMore is required LoadMore layout can be hidden by calling

```
recycler.hideLoadMore();
```

More example can be found [here](https://github.com/hereshem/Easy-RecyclerView-Library)

Hope this helps :)