# Pagination not working with staggered grid layout android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

Hello im trying to include pagination in my recylerview but dont know why it is not working with
staggeredgrid layout   [this the question im searching for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview) and becuase the answer are for linearlayoutmanager i got an answer for how to implement pagination in staggerdgrid layoutmanager  [here is the answer i tried in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463560/findfirstvisibleitempositions-doesnt-work-for-recycleview-android/45768855#45768855) after implementing it the images are not loading

**ScreenShot** // ss of what im getting right now

[image]

**short code**

```
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    int visibleThreshold = 1;
    ContentLoadingProgressBar contentLoadingProgressBar;
    private boolean isLoading = false;


contentLoadingProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.contentLoadingProgressBar);
 final StaggeredGridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) postRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = Objects.requireNonNull(linearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
                int lastVisibleItem = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
                int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    getData();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });

public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }
```

**full code**

```
public class Profile_Fragment extends Fragment implements PostAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    private final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    PostAdapter postsAdapter;
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;
    RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    Button editProfileButton;
    CircleImageView profilePhoto;
    ContentLoadingProgressBar contentLoadingProgressBar;
    int visibleThreshold = 1;
    private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
    private ValueEventListener databaseEventListener;
    private boolean isLoading = false;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        ImageView accountSettings = view.findViewById(R.id.account_Settings);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.snipet_profile);
        profilePhoto = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
        editProfileButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_button);
        contentLoadingProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.contentLoadingProgressBar);
        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
            assert getFragmentManager() != null;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });
        accountSettings.setOnClickListener(
                v -> {
                    BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
                    bottomSheet.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheet.getTag());
                }
        );
        postRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerViewProfile);
        shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmerEffect);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        );
        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) postRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                assert linearLayoutManager != null;
                int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
                int lastVisibleItem = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
                int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    getData();
                }
            }
        });
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        postsAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mUploads);
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
        postsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Profile_Fragment.this);
        return view;
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    private void getData() {
        contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        databaseEventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mUploads.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        Objects.requireNonNull(upload).setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);


                    }

                }

                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
        Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
        String selectedKey = selectedItem.getmKey();
        StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getmImageUrl());
        imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
            databaseReference.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Post Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(aVoid -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(databaseEventListener);
    }

}
```

**Update 1**

added adapter.class

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    public Context mcontext;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
//    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;


    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mUploads = uploads;
        mcontext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_profile, parent, false);
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container_profile, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        Shimmer shimmer = new Shimmer.ColorHighlightBuilder()
                .setBaseColor(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3"))
                .setBaseAlpha(1)
                .setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"))
                .setHighlightAlpha(1)
                .setDropoff(50)
                .build();
        ShimmerDrawable shimmerDrawable = new ShimmerDrawable();
        shimmerDrawable.setShimmer(shimmer);
        Glide.with(mcontext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getmImageUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                .placeholder(shimmerDrawable)
                .centerCrop()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(View view);

        void onItemClick(int position);

        void onDeleteClick(int position);
    }

    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        ShapeableImageView imageView;

        PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    mListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");
            delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (item.getItemId() == 2) {
                        mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Paging` from the Jetpack?

Comment: no i dint tried that because i think jetpack can only use with kotlin probably

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class Profile_Fragment extends Fragment implements PostAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
    private final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    PostAdapter  postsAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mUploads);;
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;
    RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    Button editProfileButton;
    CircleImageView profilePhoto;
    ContentLoadingProgressBar contentLoadingProgressBar;
    int visibleThreshold = 1;
    private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
    private ValueEventListener databaseEventListener;
    private boolean isLoading = false;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        ImageView accountSettings = view.findViewById(R.id.account_Settings);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.snipet_profile);
        profilePhoto = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
        editProfileButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_button);
        contentLoadingProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.contentLoadingProgressBar);
        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
            assert getFragmentManager() != null;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });
        accountSettings.setOnClickListener(
                v -> {
                    BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
                    bottomSheet.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheet.getTag());
                }
        );
        postRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerViewProfile);
        shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmerEffect);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        );
        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) postRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
          
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);

        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                assert linearLayoutManager != null;
                int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
                int lastVisibleItem = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
                int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    getData();
                }
                postadapter.mUploads=mUploads

                  postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
       
      
        postsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Profile_Fragment.this);
        return view;
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    private void getData() {
        contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        databaseEventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mUploads.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        Objects.requireNonNull(upload).setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);


                    }

                }

                
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
        Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
        String selectedKey = selectedItem.getmKey();
        StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getmImageUrl());
        imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
            databaseReference.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Post Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(aVoid -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(databaseEventListener);
    }

}
```

Let me Know if not working.....

Comment: can you post your adatper class code file like adapter.java

Comment: ok i have added the adapter class please check now

Comment: should i update my question with you added changes,so you can see what changes i maded