# How to implement setOnScrollListener in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-cardview, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener, endlessscroll

How Do I show progress bar at bottom when user reached to items those are visible in a list.

I have written a code in which i am getting data using web service, now i would like to populate partial records, because i have around **630 records** in my JSON.

Here is my whole code which i am using to get data from JSON and to populate into RecyclerView.

Here is how my JSON looks, but real JSON contains over 600 records:

```
 http://walldroidhd.com/api.php
```

Can someone guide me where i have to make changes in my code ?

I want to populate more records whenever user do scroll to bottom using progressbar, still i am showing all the records.

**RecyclerViewFragment.java:**

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<NatureItem> actorsList;

    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    public static RecyclerViewFragment newInstance() {
        return new RecyclerViewFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview_advance, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        actorsList = new ArrayList<NatureItem>();

        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("my JSON url");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                visibleItemCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        loading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                        <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached

                    Log.i("...", "end called");

                    // Do something

                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });

        // mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter(getActivity(), actorsList), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), mRecyclerView, null);

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
        );

    }

    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = null;
                    try {
                        data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    JSONObject jsono = null;
                    try {
                        jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("wallpapers");


                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        NatureItem actor = new NatureItem();

                        actor.setName(object.getString("id"));
                        actor.setThumbnail(object.getString("thumb_url"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (result == false) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**CardAdapter.java:**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<NatureItem> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public CardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NatureItem> feedItemList) {
        this.mItems = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        NatureItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvNature.setText(nature.getName());

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(nature.getThumbnail())
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(viewHolder.imgThumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvNature;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how i have implemented Endless as well, using [this](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e):

```
mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                // do something...
            }
        });
```

**Note:** I would personally prefer RecyclerView onScroll functionality to get my work done.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview

Comment: @AtulOHolic i have implemented recyclerview's onScrollListener() but don't know how to fetch data based on Scrolls

Comment: its a two way process. First your web service should give you pagewise data. So say when your app loaded you called page 1. Now as per the above github link implementation you can see text loadmore. This is the place you need to call your web service again but ask for next page whihc is page two in this case and so on.

Comment: Get all records in one collection. Take another collection which will populate partial records lets say 10 records. Now, when u reach at bottom, populate next 10 records in the collection and notify the list.

Comment: but when i scroll recycelrview addonscrolllistener is not calling

Comment: What is **findFirstVisibleItemPosition()**?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Activity Class with recylcerview in xml layout file

```
public class WallpaperActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTaskCompleted {


private static final String TAG = "WallpaperActivity";


private Toolbar toolbar;


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private WallPaperDataAdapter mAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
// to keep track which pages loaded and next pages to load
public static int pageNumber;

private List<WallPaper> wallpaperImagesList;


protected Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    pageNumber = 1;
    wallpaperImagesList = new ArrayList<WallPaper>();
    handler = new Handler();
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("WallPapers");

    }


    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


    // use a linear layout manager
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    // create an Object for Adapter
    mAdapter = new WallPaperDataAdapter(wallpaperImagesList, mRecyclerView);

    // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    getWebServiceData();


    mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
            wallpaperImagesList.add(null);
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(wallpaperImagesList.size() - 1);
            ++pageNumber;


            getWebServiceData();


        }
    });


}


public void getWebServiceData() {

    BackGroundTask backGroundTask = new BackGroundTask(this, this, pageNumber);
    backGroundTask.execute();

}


@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(String response) {


    parsejosnData(response);

}


public void parsejosnData(String response) {

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

        //    String json = jsonObject.toString();

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("wallpapers");


        if (jsonArray != null) {
            // looping through All albums


            if (pageNumber > 1) {
                wallpaperImagesList.remove(wallpaperImagesList.size() - 1);
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(wallpaperImagesList.size());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item values in variable
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String orig_url = c.getString("orig_url");
                String thumb_url = c.getString("thumb_url");
                String downloads = c.getString("downloads");
                String fav = c.getString("fav");

                // Creating object for each product
                WallPaper singleWall = new WallPaper(id, orig_url, thumb_url, downloads, fav);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                wallpaperImagesList.add(singleWall);


                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(wallpaperImagesList.size());


                    }
                });


            }


            mAdapter.setLoaded();


        } else {
            Log.d("Wallpapers: ", "null");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class WallPaperDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    private List<WallPaper> imagesList;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;


    public WallPaperDataAdapter(List<WallPaper> imagesList1, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        imagesList = imagesList1;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();


            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return imagesList.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                      int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.wallpaper_row, parent, false);

            vh = new WallPaperViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progress_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof WallPaperViewHolder) {

            WallPaper singleWallPaper = (WallPaper) imagesList.get(position);


            Glide.with(((WallPaperViewHolder) holder).thumbIcon.getContext())
                    .load(singleWallPaper.getThumbUrl())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.bg)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(((WallPaperViewHolder) holder).thumbIcon);


        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagesList.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }


    //
    public static class WallPaperViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public ImageView thumbIcon;


        public WallPaperViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);


            thumbIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbIcon);


        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }
}
```

wallpaper_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbIcon"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

progress_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Separate BackGroundTask.java

```
public class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public OnTaskCompleted listener = null;//Call back interface


    Context context;
    int pageNumber;

    public BackGroundTask(Context context1, OnTaskCompleted listener1, int pageNumber) {
        context = context1;
        listener = listener1;   //Assigning call back interface  through constructor
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

        //My Background tasks are written here

        synchronized (this) {

            String url = Const.URL_WALLPAPERS_HD + pageNumber;
            String jsonStr = ServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.i("Url: ", "> " + url);

            Log.i("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            return jsonStr;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        listener.onTaskCompleted(result);

    }

}
```

ServiceHanlder.java

```
public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;


    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     *
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     */
    public static String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     *
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     */
    public static String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }
                Log.e("Selltis Request URL", url);
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += paramString;

                    Log.i("Request URL", url);
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Fail";
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Fail";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Fail";
        }

        return response;

    }


}
```

Interface for Load More

```
public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
     void onLoadMore();
}
```

Interface to know web service data loaded from asynctask

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted{

    void onTaskCompleted(String response);
}
```

Please let me know if this works or any issues for you. 
Better to use Volley or okHttp Libraries for Networking.

For ImageLoading i used [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) Library.

Comment: i have tried facing small issues, please share a link of complete source code

Comment: Code at @github https://github.com/kprathap23/Android/tree/master/EndlessRecyclerView. Please let me know if you find any issues

Comment: hello have a look at this issue, i am using your demo project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946441/recyclerview-endless-infinite-scrolling-issue

Comment: i tried but one time only calling addonscroll or loadmore is not every time

Comment: i will check the code again. long time back i given the answer. can u check this library to add load more if u prefer to use library https://github.com/jianghejie/XRecyclerView

Comment: I tried your demo project.It is not triggering  `addOnScrollListener` when scrolling recyclerview items.

Answer (score 26):

This is how I detect whether `RecyclerView` should refresh by `OnScrollListener`, take a look at it:

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    int ydy = 0;
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int offset = dy - ydy;
        ydy = dy;
        boolean shouldRefresh = (linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0)
                && (recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) && offset > 30;
        if (shouldRefresh) {
            //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            //Refresh to load data here.
            return;
        }
        boolean shouldPullUpRefresh = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == linearLayoutManager.getChildCount() - 1
                && recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && offset < -30;
        if (shouldPullUpRefresh) {
            //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            //refresh to load data here.
            return;
        }
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```

Hope you'll be inspired. Good luck~

Comment: could u please specify who is `ydy` and what is its initial value? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

To implement OnScrollListener in **Kotlin** for RecyclerView, you can use

```
recyclerViewChat.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Log.d("scroll", "idle")
                } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                    Log.d("scroll", "settling")
                } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    Log.d("scroll", "dragging")
                }
            }

            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                Log.d("scroll", "scrolling")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 4):

*Another example*. Set you progress bar at bottom and change its visibility according to scrolling/loading and your records. Note: you need to call notifyDataSetChanged(); method to add/refresh data to adapter

```
  recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int total = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                int firstVisibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int lastVisibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                //to avoid multiple calls to loadMore() method
                //maintain a boolean value (isLoading). if loadMore() task started set to true and completes set to false
                if (!isLoading) { 
                    if (total > 0) 
                        if ((total - 1) == lastVisibleItemCount){
                           loadMore();//your HTTP stuff goes in this method 
                           loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else
                           loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            }

    });
```

Comment: i have used your code to implement recyclerView.setOnScrollListener    but   my problem is when i run app and scroll to bottom it loads next page and trigger last item of next page and then it does not go beyond 2nd page,   here is my code :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863060/android-recyclerview-addonscrolllistener-trigger-last-item-in-recyclerview

Comment: recyclerView.setOnScrollListener is depricated

Comment: use addOnScrollListener

Answer (score 1):

In the onScroll method

```
if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
        <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
    // End has been reached

    Log.i("...", "end called");

    // Do something
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://walldroidhd.com/api.php");

    loading = true;
}
```

Comment: this is just to load next records from web service after you reach the end while scrolling. not to show progress bar on the bottom.you need change the adapter class and asynctask a little bit to get this functionality.

Comment: I am facing issue in this way. While implementing search in recycler view and suppose there is only 1 item, extra api call will occur.

Answer (score 1):

The idea to implement load-more is :

> Get all records in one collection. Take another collection which will populate partial records lets say 10 records. Now, when u reach at bottom, populate next 10 records in the collection and notify the list.

So your code will be something like this :

```
ArrayList<NatureItem> tempList; // which holds partial records
tempList = getList(limit, 10);

mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new CardAdapter(getActivity(), tempList), 2);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now, code to load next records :

```
limit += 10;
tempList.addAll(getList(limit, 10));
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To show he loader/progress, better to use [load-more library](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)

Answer (score 0):

Now accepted answer as @SilentKnight suggested will not work as setOnscroll is deprecated by Android SDK.

You should use

```
recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        int ydy = 0;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int offset = dy - ydy;
            ydy = dy;
            boolean shouldRefresh = (linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0)
                    && (recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) && offset > 30;
            if (shouldRefresh) {
                //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                //Refresh to load data here.
                return;
            }
            boolean shouldPullUpRefresh = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == linearLayoutManager.getChildCount() - 1
                    && recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && offset < -30;
            if (shouldPullUpRefresh) {
                //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                //refresh to load data here.
                return;
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```