# Detecting up and down swipes on a Recyclerview in a fragment how can I do that?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a recyclerview loaded with Firebase Firestore Documents and I want to see if it is beeing swiped up or down. Depending on the direction I want to make the adapter.startListening(); again and stop if he swipes down. I also want to hide a button if the user scrolls down. I just need to figure out how can I see if he does that ?

This piece of code was working with left and right but for some reason won´t with up and down ?

```
        new ItemTouchHelper( new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.UP){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You swiped up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Here the complete code if it some reason interfers with smth don´t know

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    View myFragment;
    private ImageButton postButton;
    CollectionReference postsRef;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    private PostsAdapter adapter;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public static ProfileFragment getInstance() {
        return new ProfileFragment();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        postButton = myFragment.findViewById( R.id.postButton);
        recyclerView = myFragment.findViewById(R.id.postlist);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        postsRef = db.collection("posts");
        SetupRecyclerView();
        postButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendUserToPostActivity();
            }
        });



        new ItemTouchHelper( new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.UP){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You swiped up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        adapter.setOnConfirmClickListener( new PostsAdapter.onConfirmClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConfirmClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Posts post = documentSnapshot.toObject(Posts.class);
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                if(post.getUid().equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                    adapter.deleteItem(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You cannot delete this", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    private void SetupRecyclerView() {
        Query query = postsRef.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Posts> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>().setQuery(query, Posts.class).build();
        adapter = new PostsAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void SendUserToPostActivity() {
        Intent postIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class);
        startActivity(postIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000964/how-to-implement-setonscrolllistener-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong listener. An `ItemTouchHelper` applies to the individual items within the recyclerview, rather than the view as whole.

What you're looking for is `OnScrollListener`:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                //This is where you can track a scroll change
            }
        });
```

`dy` in the `onScrolled` method refers to the change in y position on a scroll event, likewise for `dx`.

In that method, let's say you wanted to check if the recyclerview reached the limit of scrolling either up or down, then within that `onScroll` method (or wherever you're checking that), you can add a call to `recyclerView.canScrollVertically(int)`. The `int` will be a value of -1 for UP, 1 for DOWN, and 0 for FALSE, i.e. cannot scroll.

Checking if the recyclerview reached the bottom:

```
if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){
    //The recyclerview can no longer scroll downwards, you have reached the bottom
}
```

Editing to add: Your `itemTouchHelper` also didn't work correctly because vertical directions are to be specified in the first parameter of the callback, and horizontal directions in the second parameter. You passed 0 for the first parameter, so it sees no vertical direction as an option

Comment: Yo thx a bunch helped me a lot but my only question is now how can I check if the last scroll was a downscroll ?

Comment: No prob, and you can check the direction through the value of ```dy```: ```dy``` > 0 for scrolls down, ```dy``` < 0 for scrolls up