# How create Recycler View Grid pagination?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created Recycler View Grid. And I want realize pagination. But I do not understand how do it. I Found one answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)

But it not work for me. I have not method  `mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();` in my LayOutManager. And method `mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener` is deprecated. How can I realize pagination in Recycler View Grid?

Comment: For one thing, findFirstVisibleItemPosition is a method of the LinearLayoutManager implementation, and you just need to use addOnScrollListener.

Comment: Thank you for  addOnScrollListener. What about GridLayoutManager? How can i do it?

Comment: GridLayoutManager is a subclass of LinearLayoutManager.  GLM has the findFirstVisibleItemPosition method.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but you can try this..and It works perfectly

```
allMovie_recycler_view.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if (dy > 0) {

                val layoutManager = allMovie_recycler_view.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager
                val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()+1
                if (visibleItemCount == layoutManager.itemCount){
                    //Load more data
                }


            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the proper way to paginate with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

The only difference is in `findFirstVisibleItemPositions()`, which returns an `int[]` for the first visible position in each span.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = mGridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int[] firstVisibleItemPositions = mGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null);

        if (!mIsLoading && !mIsLastPage) {
            if ((firstVisibleItemPositions[0] + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPositions[0] >= 0
                && totalItemCount >= Config.PAGE_SIZE) {
                loadMorePosts();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: findFirstVisibleItemPosition return a integer not a int[] also it is 'findFirstVisibleItemPosition' not 'findFirstVisibleItemPositions'

Answer (score -3):

I know the answer is late. For others who may encounter this, use this solution.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(mRecyclerViewOnScrollListener);

private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
        mRecyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                     int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!isLoading && currentPage < totalPages) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                    && totalItemCount >= numberOfItemsInAPage) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }
};
```