# How do I create a circular (endless) RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make my `RecyclerView` loop back to the start of my list.

I have searched all over the internet and have managed to detect when I have reached the end of my list, however I am unsure where to proceed from here.

This is what I am currently using to detect the end of the list (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)):

```
 @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if ( (visibleItemCount+pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                loading = false;
                Log.v("...", ""+visibleItemCount);
            }
        }
 }
```

When scrolled to the end, I would like to views to be visible while the displaying data from the top of the list or when scrolled to the top of the list I would display data from the bottom of the list.

For example:

> View1 View2 View3 View4 View5
>
> View5 View1 View2 View3 View4

Comment: @DamianKozlak RecyclerView is not same as ListView

Comment: @ChadBingham Of course not, but this problem could be resolved using the same solution like in `ListView`. Both `ListView` and `RecyclerView` adapters got `getCount()` and `getItem()` methods.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am working on the same problem, currently I am thinking of writing a custom LayoutManager extending from LinearLayoutManager. Did you ever achieve your goal?

Comment: yeah Sebastian's answer below worked for me. It was the simplest solution I found.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There is no way of making it infinite, but there is a way to make it look like infinite.

1. in your adapter override `getCount()` to return something big like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

   ```
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   }
   ```
2. in `getItem()` and `getView()` modulo divide (%) position by real item number:

   ```
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       int positionInList = position % fragmentList.size();
       return fragmentList.get(positionInList);
   }
   ```
3. at the end, set current item to something in the middle (or else, it would be endless only in downward direction).

   ```
   // scroll to middle item
   recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
   ```

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I do, but I cannot call smoothScrollToPosition() with negative value. I want my list can be dpad controlled and can scroll left direction as well as right direction.

Comment: @anhtuannd Use MAX_INT / 2 or whatever as the starting position.

Comment: Great idea! One improvement is to show the same first item after scrollTo() call.
Could be:
int number = Integer.MAX_VALUE / items.size() / 2; scrollToPosition(number * items.size());

Comment: I don't understand how this work's, in first place we are talking about Recyclerview adapter ,from where does getItem / getView comes here.

Comment: @geniushkg That is actually simpler. You don't need to override any method, but just use another position (e.g. realPosition) where it = `position % itemList.size()` in your `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: Hi, i'm still confused about the question asked by @geniushkg, lets say I declared (int myPosition = position % itemList.Size()) in my OnBindViewholder, where should i use myPosition ?

Comment: Since when did a big number (2 billion) become infinite? First this is bounded meaning it will reach the end at some point, second it doesn't seem very memory efficient creating 2 billion cells..

Comment: It does not have to be infinite. It just have to look like it. The thing it is does not create 2 billion cells. It is using same cells in a kind of loop using modulo operation. In terms of reaching the end you are right. Of course it is going to reach it, but for 2^31 and assuming scrolling one item is 0,5second, the end is reachable in 17years of scrolling. Good luck ;)

Comment: @6rchid it's a recyclerview, it doesn't create all the memory. It reuses it when it needs to.

Comment: Some how `Integer.MAX_VALUE` does not work properly with reverseLayout and StackfromEnd True.

Comment: This solution handles it easily, but can the device crash due to ram usage?

Comment: use
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition((Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)-(size-1))
for item starting from first position.

Comment: For Accessibility is there a way to announce the items as "1 of 5, in list of 5 items" instead of "1072741820 of 2147483640, in list of 2147483640 items" ?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not useful when your list could possibly have 0 items and then items are added. (After the items are added you will now find yourself at the very top of the list unable to scroll up.)

Comment: onBindViewHolder running infinintely, and getting memory issue, how can I stop looping onBindViewHolder()

Answer (score 28):

The other solutions i found for this problem work well enough, but i think there might be some memory issues returning Integer.MAX_VALUE in getCount() method of recycler view.

To fix this, override getItemCount() method as below :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList == null ? 0 : itemList.size() * 2;
}
```

Now wherever you are using the position to get the item from the list, use below

```
position % itemList.size()
```

Now add scrollListener to your recycler view

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) { 
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int firstItemVisible = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (firstItemVisible != 0 && firstItemVisible % itemList.size() == 0) {
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Finally to start auto scrolling, call the method below

```
public void autoScroll() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.scrollBy(2, 0);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
}
```

Comment: mine only repeated one time with this method, e.g. i entered dummy data 1,2,3,4, it only show 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4, rather than keep looping infinitely, what did i do wrong ?

Comment: @BeeingJk in the getItemCount function, we are returning twice the elements in our list, that is why for you it is repeating only twice. Try returning 4-5 times the number of elements in your list then it should work properly.

Comment: thanks @NikhilGupta, i have figured it out, because of my data length is too short that `firstItemVisible % itemList.size() == 0` never happen, and yea returning 3 times make it work, but I can't guarantee it will work all the time so I do compare the total data length with RecyclerView width before enabling auto scroll, can't find an easier way so far

Comment: I am not able to loop back to the end from the start, but its is looping to the start from the end. Is there a way I can go either direction.

Comment: from where i need to call autoScroll() method please help.

Comment: @umeshshakya You can call autoscroll from anywhere. Just make sure you have initialised your recyclerView and set adapter and other things you need to set.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilGupta ! Do you know a way to loop back to end from the start please?

Comment: @NayMak for looping also backward use whats mentioned in the selected answer - recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2); after the recycler view is initiated and make sure your getCount method returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Amazing. Found exactly what I was looking for. For smooth scrolling without issues.

Answer (score 12):

I have created a [LoopingLayoutManager](https://github.com/BeksOmega/looping-layout) that fixes this issue.

It works without having to modify the adapter, which allows for greater flexibility and reusability.

It comes fully featured with support for:

- Vertical and Horizontal Orientations
- LTR and RTL
- ReverseLayout for both orientations, as well as LTR, and RTL
- Public functions for finding items and positions
- Public functions for scrolling programmatically
- Snap Helper support
- Accessibility (TalkBack and Voice Access) support

And it is hosted on maven central, which means you just need to add it as a dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.beksomega:loopinglayout:0.3.1'
}
```

and change your `LinearLayoutManager` to a `LoopingLayoutManager`.

It has a suite of 132 unit tests that make me confident it's stable, but if you find any bugs please put up an issue on the [github](https://github.com/BeksOmega/looping-layout)!

I hope this helps!

Comment: This great but I am noticing an issue where items jump positions while scrolling.

Comment: Thank you for trying out my project @DaveThomas! I also really appreciate you reporting a bug about it. I've never seen that issue, so I can't give you advice immediately. But if you fill out an [issue](https://github.com/BeksOmega/looping-layout/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) I may be able to track it down.

Comment: For me the suggested library works like a charm. I appreciate that it also supports `LinearSnapHelper`!

Comment: Now I see that the problem with `LoopingLayoutManager` is that it lays out/renders the very same `View` instance multiple times. At the first glance it looks great, but this approach doesn't count with the scenario if one needs to update the item e.g. `onClick`. In such situation the behavior is unspecified (a bit of a mess) because the items which were not clicked also updates their UI. This happens because the items share the same `View` instance. The aforementioned `Integer.MAX_VALUE % 2` approach might not be the cleanest one from the coding point of view, but works for this scenario.

Comment: seems it doesn't support add or remove item, the LinearLayoutManager would  auto scroll to next item after current item was deleted

Answer (score 2):

In addition to solution above.
For endless recycler view in both sides you should add something like that:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            val firstItemVisible = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            if (firstItemVisible != 1 && firstItemVisible % songs.size == 1) {
                linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(1)
            }
            val firstCompletelyItemVisible = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            if (firstCompletelyItemVisible == 0) {
                linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(songs.size, 0)
            }
        }
    })
```

And upgrade your getItemCount() method:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList == null ? 0 : itemList.size() * 2 + 1;
}
```

It is work like unlimited down-scrolling, but in both directions. Glad to help!

Comment: It doesn't get the first item after the last tho it just scrolls back to top

Answer (score 2):

Amended @afanit's solution to prevent the infinite scroll from momentarily halting when scrolling in the reverse direction (due to waiting for the 0th item to become completely visible, which allows the scrollable content to run out before `scrollToPosition()` is called):

```
val firstItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
if (firstItemPosition != 1 && firstItemPosition % items.size == 1) {
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(1)
} else if (firstItemPosition == 0) {
    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(items.size, -recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset())
}
```

Note the use of `computeHorizontalScrollOffset()` because my layout manager is horizontal.

Also, I found that the minimum return value from `getItemCount()` for this solution to work is `items.size + 3`. Items with position larger than this are never reached.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into OOM issues with Glide and other APIs and created this Implementation using the Duplicate End Caps inspired by this post for an iOS build.

Might look intimidating but its literally just copying the RecyclerView class and updating two methods in your RecyclerView Adapter. All it is doing is that once it hits the end caps, it does a quick no-animation transition to either ends of the adapter's ViewHolders to allow continuous cycling transitions.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

```
class CyclingRecyclerView(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet?
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs) {
    // --------------------- Instance Variables ------------------------
    private val onScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            // The total number of items in our RecyclerView
            val itemCount = adapter?.itemCount ?: 0

            // Only continue if there are more than 1 item, otherwise, instantly return
            if (itemCount <= 1) return

            // Once the scroll state is idle, check what position we are in and scroll instantly without animation
            if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                // Get the current position
                val pos = (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

                // If our current position is 0,
                if (pos == 0) {
                    Log.d("AutoScrollingRV", "Current position is 0, moving to ${itemCount - 1} when item count is $itemCount")
                    scrollToPosition(itemCount - 2)
                } else if (pos == itemCount - 1) {
                    Log.d("AutoScrollingRV", "Current position is ${itemCount - 1}, moving to 1 when item count is $itemCount")
                    scrollToPosition(1)
                } else {
                    Log.d("AutoScrollingRV", "Curren position is $pos")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
    }
}
```

For the Adapter, just make sure to update 2 methods, in my case, viewModels is just my data structure that contains the data that I send over to my ViewHolders

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int = if (viewModels.size > 1) viewModels.size + 2 else viewModels.size
```

and on ViewHolder, you just retrieve the adjusted index's data

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val adjustedPos: Int =
            if (viewModels.size > 1) {
                when (position) {
                    0 -> viewModels.lastIndex
                    viewModels.size + 1 -> 0
                    else -> position - 1
                }
            } else {
                position
            }
        holder.bind(viewModels[adjustedPos])
    }
```

The previous implementation's hurt me haha, seemed way to hacky to just add a crazy amount of items, big problem when you run into Multiple cards with an Integer.MAX_VALUE nested RecyclerView. This approach fixed all the problems of OOM since it only necessarily creates 2 and ViewHolders.

Answer (score -2):

Endless recyclerView in both sides

Add onScrollListener at your recyclerview

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int firstItemVisible = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (firstItemVisible != 1 && firstItemVisible % itemList.size() == 1) {
                ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(1);
            }
            int firstCompletelyItemVisible = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (firstCompletelyItemVisible == 0)
            {}

            if (firstItemVisible != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
                    && firstItemVisible== recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()%itemList.size() - 1)
            {
                ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(itemList.size() + 1, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

In your adapter override the getItemCount method

```
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return itemList == null ? 0 : itemList.size() * 2 + 1;
}
```