# RecyclerView how to make cyclic

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView with elements, for example from 1 to 10. Can somebody help? Thanks!

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  //On create

and when I scroll i want to make something like this:

9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 //On Scroll

5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the following question which answers a similar problem: [How do I create a circular (endless) RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253555/how-to-create-a-circular-endless-recyclerview)