# Android Recycler View Horizontal Scroll to last item and show the first item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Currently I'm working on a recycler view that has a horizontal scroll.

I have a list that contains these values:

> {"2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010",...}

and so on, until 2017

My objective here is to select the year on the **center**

All works good but I have 2 problems here :

1. I can't scroll to the right edge, it's like the recyclerview has its limit on scrolling. Let's say the 4 last items are `"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"`. I can only scroll until "2003". For now i fix this issue by adding a **dummy years** before and after the list. (very hackish, but not so solid)
2. I want to show the first child when the scrolling reaches the end. For example, when I'm able to scroll until the end **2017** , I want to show the first item of the list right next to **2017** and in this case is **"2001"**. For example: 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | **2001** | ...

Comment: why cant you show 2018,2019... with disabled text in that list?

Comment: no the last value is 2017, i dont need to show value beyond it, what i need to show is 2001 after 2017 (show the first item next to 2017)

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909927/recyclerview-how-to-make-cyclic

Comment: you can try https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap

Answer (score 1):

what you should use here is loop your recyclerview

in your adapter override getItemCount() to return something big like Integer.MAX_VALUE:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

in onBindViewHolder() modulo divide (%) position by real item number:

```
 @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int positionInList = position % dataList.size();
        Item item = dataList.get(positionInList);
        //...
    }
```

at the end, set current item to something in the middle (or else, it would be endless only in downward direction).

```
// scroll to middle item
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
```

Comment: i think it should be dataList.get(positionInList). i ll give it a try tho

Comment: Good solution, suggesting to calculate `dataList.size()` outside once onBind for better performance

Comment: For anyone looking for a kotlin reference : https://github.com/mdroid23/AutoScrollRecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(5);
```

you can put your item number here in place of 5, can do (list.size()-3) for specific year.