# Looped Flexible Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to get endless (looped) RecyclerView. But I use custom library for Adapter - [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter):

I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253555/how-to-create-a-circular-endless-recyclerview) the correct answer for usual RecyclerView.Adapter:

But I can't modify `getItemCount()` method

Do you have any alternative ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you create a new Adapter extending the FlexibleAdapter and override the getItemCount() method?

Comment: No, because getItemCount() is final. After fork and override this method, I get new issues

Answer (score 1):

[Endless / Loading More](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/wiki/5.x-%7C-On-Load-More) feature is part of library since January 2017. Top Endless from June 2017.