# How do I make an infinitely looping RecyclerView while also being able to scroll to an item programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I want to make a RecyclerView that scrolls infinitely while also being able to scroll to an item programmatically.

At the moment I've made the RecyclerView loop infinitely using this hacky method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31254146/7443375

i.e. Overriding my adapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Getting position of item in my adapter like so:

```
    int positionInList = position % fragmentList.size();
```

And then initializing my RecyclerView's scroll position like so:

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
```

However, in my Fragment that has the RecyclerView, I want to be able to scroll to a specific item in my list (i.e. item 3 out of a list of 10 items). When I call

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(2);
```

The list goes into an infinite scroll. I can't figure out how to go to the specific item itself.

Furthermore, how can I make sure that the specific item is centered in the screen? I am using LinearSnapHelper to snap the items in the center of the screen as I scroll, but LinearSnapHelper does not seem to work when setting positions programmatically.

Comment: Provide some more code please, specially if you hace onScroll Listeners. Inifinite scrolling is little Mysterious in your case

Comment: @MohammedAtif I don't have any more code related to the RecyclerView; on a button click I simply want to scroll to a specified position in the list (i.e. scrollToPosition(2)). I think what's happening is the recyclerview position is set at Integer.MAX_VALUE/2 and scrollToPosition(2) causes the RecyclerView to try to scroll all the way back to position 2

Answer (score 1):

Try this way..

```
    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                new CountDownTimer(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 20 ) {
                                    public void onTick(long millis) {
                                        recyclerView.scrollBy(0, 20);
                                    }

                                public void onFinish() {

                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this code does. Does the recyclerview atrbitrarily get scrolled by 20 pixels every 20ms?

Comment: yes, its auto scrolling every 20ms and by 20 px height

Comment: How does this help me accomplish scrolling to a specific position? It seems to be scrolling infinitely.

Comment: what is your question? you want infinitely scrolling

Comment: I want to be able to have the recyclerview be never-ending (i.e. when I get to the start or end of the list, the list loops) and also be able to scroll to a certain item in the recyclerview through code (i.e. call smoothScrollToPosition(3))