# Snap center onItemClick in cyclic Recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

**Description:** I am working on one demo with the functionality that user can select an option from the item of horizontal `Recyclerview`. In this, I got stuck in below queries.

**Queries:**

**1:**  *How to make `Recyclerview` cyclic?*

For example, I have 10 items named 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Now if user scrolls the recyclerview then he/she will be able to scroll it endlessly. i.e 1,2,3,4,5...9,10,1,2...9,10,1,2,3..9,10 like this.
To achieve this I have used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45114415/7874047). Somehow it worked but only in forward direction.

**2:** *How to give Snap center to the particular item which is selected by the user?*

For example: **As shown in the image**, if the user clicks on '15' then that item will come to the center. Same as if the user clicks on '07' then it should come to the center position.
I have implemented [this demo](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/SnapHelperExample). But it doesn't work on click on the item.

The code which I have done so far is as below:

Layout Manager:

```
final CenterZoomLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new CenterZoomLayoutManager(mContext,
            CenterZoomLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);// To get centered item zoom
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Adapter object:

```
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, arrayList, new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position) {

        }
    });
    recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

[image: Horizontal Recylerview in which user can select item as an option]

Answer (score 0):

**CarouselView** may fulfill your requirements. Please check following GitHub links for the same.

- https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1481
- https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
- https://www.pocketmagic.net/a-3d-carousel-view-for-android/
- https://github.com/clkasd/CarouselViewProject

Answer (score 0):

[How do I create a circular (endless) RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253555/how-do-i-create-a-circular-endless-recyclerview?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> There is no way of making it infinite, but there is a way to make it
>   look like infinite.
>
> in your adapter override getCount() to return something big like
>   Integer.MAX_VALUE:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

> in getItem() and getView() modulo divide (%) position by real item
>   number:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    int positionInList = position % fragmentList.size();
    return fragmentList.get(positionInList);
}
```

> at the end, set current item to something in the middle (or else, it
>   would be endless only in downward direction).

```
// scroll to middle item
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
```

**For snapping**
 use SnapHelper or scrollToPositionWithOffset, where offset is (width/2 - itemWidth/2)

Answer (score 0):

I can use this library
You can solve your problem by personalizing this library. By selecting each item, you can use the ScrollToX function to navigate to that item.

https://github.com/mahdimoaz/RecyclerViewHorizontalCenterSelected