# Make Endless RecycleView with Fixed data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-loop

How to create endless Recycle view, what i mean suppose i have 50 record fixed i what to make endless scroll with this data,

Recycle view with this 50 record, when it at the end start from the first record.

Comment: have u check this [How do I create a circular (endless) RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31253555/7666442)

Comment: i check both but it contains load more option with add data i don't want this, b'coz i have fixed data