# How do you override a RecyclerView item index for accessibility?

Tags: android, kotlin, talkback, accessibility

I built an endless horizontal recycler view similar to the one in the solution of this post: [How do I create a circular (endless) RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253555/how-do-i-create-a-circular-endless-recyclerview/31254146#comment120726616_31254146) with 5 total items.

Currently because the count of the list is `Int.MAX_INTEGER`, TalkBack dictates the view as

> "1073741820 of 2147483650, in list, 2147483650 items"

For Accessibility, what can I do to have TalkBack to describe the contents of each item as

> "1 of 5, in list, 5 items" etc for each item.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
    private fun setupAccessibility() {
    val recyclerView = binding.viewPager.getChildAt(0) as? RecyclerView ?: return
    recyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(object :
        RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate(recyclerView) {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
            host: View?,
            info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat?
        ) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            info?.collectionInfo?.run {
                info.setCollectionInfo(
                    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.CollectionInfoCompat.obtain(
                        max(1, rowCount % ITEMS_COUNT),
                        max(1, columnCount % ITEMS_COUNT),
                        isHierarchical,
                        selectionMode
                    )
                )
            }
        }

        override fun sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(host: View?, event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
            super.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(host, event)
            event?.apply {
                fromIndex %= ITEMS_COUNT
                toIndex %= ITEMS_COUNT
                itemCount = ITEMS_COUNT
            }
        }

        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host: View?, event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host, event)
            event?.apply {
                fromIndex %= ITEMS_COUNT
                toIndex %= ITEMS_COUNT
                itemCount = ITEMS_COUNT
            }
        }

        override fun getItemDelegate(): AccessibilityDelegateCompat {
            return object : ItemDelegate(this) {
                override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
                    host: View?,
                    info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat?
                ) {
                    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                    info?.collectionItemInfo?.run {
                        info.setCollectionItemInfo(
                            AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.CollectionItemInfoCompat.obtain(
                                rowIndex % ITEMS_COUNT,
                                rowSpan,
                                columnIndex % ITEMS_COUNT,
                                columnSpan,
                                info.isHeading,
                                isSelected
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Where ITEMS_COUNT is actual number of items (data items count)

Answer (score 0):

The number can be changed using [AccessibilityDelegateCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat), specifically, [CollectionInfoCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.CollectionInfoCompat) would allow to set `rowCount` to 5, instead of `Int.MAX_INTEGER`.

However, with this, custom circular navigation likely would not work anymore when using Talkback.