# How to implement Two-phased loads in recyclerview?

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

Can you show me how to implement the pattern "Two-phased loads" in   [Google Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/progress-activity.html#progress-activity-behavior) with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)?

Comment: There is similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to using this via [rv-adapter-endless](https://github.com/rockerhieu/rv-adapter-endless)