# How to fill data in RecyclerView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

My app is using `RecyclerView` to load the data from `Backend Endpoints API`. After connecting the `API` I am getting some `x amount` of data. I am successfully able to load the data in `StaggeredGridView` in `RecylerView`.

Now, user `scrolldown` to bottom and reach at `Last Position`. How can I make able to another request to fetch next `x` amount of data and so on?
**(Like Gmail App does. Gmail app shows a spinner and load next span of data)**

I am new in Android and How can I achieve it?

Comment: It depends on `Backend Endpoints API` supporting lazy loading :)

Comment: Like @ρяσѕρєяK said, if the API supports paging, just make a request for the next page, add the contents of the request to the collection that the adapter points to, then `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: How can I check it? I can only expose the API. In my case I have something like this : `abc.com?limit=100` where 100 is x

Comment: @nukeforum checkout my first comment. It's possible then?

Comment: @nukeforum Can you give me an example or link where I can look at it?

Comment: May you find this link helpful in getting the desired result   https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e

Comment: @AmitPal I don't know what API you're using. If you look at the documentation for the API, I'm sure they will list paging as an option if it is available.

Comment: @nukeforum Pagination is available in the API.

Comment: @AmitPal Cool, check out Natan's answer for a technique for making this request at the right time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple, just check the onScrolled event. You can check this answer for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643292/4244598

You can also start loading before the user reacher the end of the list if you wish. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I looked at it but didn't able to understand where the accepted answer or Kushal answer is calling backend API after the user reached to last position of recyclerView?

Comment: You can call the backend right after the loading = false;

Comment: Actually I did that but can you give me an hint how to append this data to the previous one in RecyclerView?

Comment: Just append the data to the list you used to create the recyclerView's adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()