# Detect RecyclerView's GridLayoutManager End Of Scroll with SuperSLiM library

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, superslim

I have been searching for a while but can't find a solution to detect end of scroll of recycler view with grid layout manager. Using code below actually work, but it is for linear layout manager not for grid layout manager.

```
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int scrollState) {
                final int treeshold = 0;
                try {
                    if (scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition() >= yourData.size()
                                - 1 - treeshold) {
                            //your load more logic
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
```

The idea is that i want to implement load more function to my application, so i need to detect end of scroll.

Edit : maybe the problem not the grid view itself. I used com.tonicartos.superslim library to get sticky header view. I wonder that it might be the problem

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26561717/4224337).

Comment: I have tried it and doesn't work, maybe it is because the sticky header library that i use, but i'm not sure yet. I will try to get another workaround

Comment: Have you tried this:

ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(mRecyclerView, 1);   ??

Comment: I got reply directly from the author in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716315/3940133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just sent an email directly to Mr. Artos about this problem and got a reply:
"It likely won't work properly until the next version is finished. I wrote about it on my blog at http://www.tonicartos.com/2015/12/superslim-milestone-1_23.html?m=1"

Answer (score 2):

Add a scroll listener to your **RecyclerView** like below:

```
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;  
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                            totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                            pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                           if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                                //bottom of recyclerview
                          }
                        }
    });
```

layoutmanager is your **GridLayoutManager**

Comment: I have tried it and doesn't work, maybe it is because the sticky header library that i use, but i'm not sure yet. I will try to get another workaround

Comment: try and disable the sticky header library and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int currentPage = 1;

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private boolean isUseLinearLayoutManager;
    private boolean isUseGridLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
        isUseLinearLayoutManager = true;

    }

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = gridLayoutManager;
        isUseGridLayoutManager = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();


        if(isUseLinearLayoutManager && mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager){
            firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        if(isUseGridLayoutManager && mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager){
            firstVisibleItem = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            currentPage++;

            onLoadMore(currentPage);

            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int currentPage);
```