# Android RecyclerView inside NestedScrollVew check isScrollToEnd

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView and its working fine but the problem is i can't listen RecyclerView's loadmore event ( custom scroll event) as i am using inside nestedscroll view so is there way to listen nested scroll view's Scroll to end event.

Comment: Do you really need to have the RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView?  RecyclerView already supports nested scrolling by default.....

Comment: Yes, because i want to use fix LinearLayout above Recyclerview

Comment: Have you tried the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26561717/4409409

Comment: Yes Daniel, as i mention in question i already create custom scroll event (load more) and it's working if I use only recycler view. **but now recycler view is inside of nested scroll view so it does not catch recycler views scroll event.** So i want something which fire NestedScroll is to end

Comment: Ok.  It's best to show the code of what you've tried so far, otherwise we have to guess as to what exactly you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution, I use fix layout as first row in RecyclerView's adapter by inserting dummy object in adapter's array list and then inflate using getViewType function