# How can I load only first 10 objects of JSON and after user scrolls load another 10 and so on?

Tags: android, json, performance

Hai I'm developing an application which will show some data in recycler view by parsing JSON.

For example if I have very large JSON response, I need my application to fetch only first 10 objects of JSON. When user scrolls down, I need to send request again to server to show 10 more.

Same like Facebook comments. It shows more comments when user scrolls down. How can I go this?

Comment: have you implement pagination in your web service

Comment: check this out https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

It is not best practice to do so you have to get that webservice in paging.

Other than that you can limit the iteration of **for loop** that you are using to parse JSON. And when the scroll is at the end Load more using this [How to implement endless list with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)