# Android RecyclerView with 1000s of data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a Sqlite db file which have 1000's of records which I want to display with `RecyclerView`. If I fetch the data and store them in a `List` it takes 10s to loop through all the data. Then when I assign this `List` to `RecyclerView` data adapter, it takes almost 10 extra seconds to cache the data for displaying. So its spending about 20s in this entire process.

Is there any why to directly connect the SQLite db query cursor with RecyclerView, so it can display data one by one instead of retrieving all 1000s of data and cache it?

Comment: Please show your code  because it easy for RecyclerView to handle just 1000 items.

Comment: yes easy, but if you have to handle images inside the list, it´s a little bit more advanced task

Comment: @Jing its in 1000s... means about 8000

Comment: you can use endless recyclerview.

Comment: @codelearner I took a test with 700,000 items on android Recyclerview sample, and found that it took nearly 0 second to fill the Recyclerview. Thus i'm sure it's not Recyclerview's problem. Perhaps, it was because of   sqlite.

Comment: @Jing thanks for your input and test... After revising my code the execution time has reduced from ~20s to only about ~500ms.

Answer (score 4):

You should use pagination for these cases.you can use queries like this :

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 //for page #1
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 // for page #2
```

and check this url to implementing pagination :
[How to implement endless list with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

Try to show the view with load more, like when user scrolls down then load the data..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Manoj.... Show some items and as the users keeps scrolling load and add next items to the list and use `notifyDataSetChanged()`.this will help you