# Endless RecyclerView Loading keeps loading without scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I have this situation. I implemented [endless scrolling with RecyclerView](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/d09dc68ff07e845cc622). Normally new items are suppose to load when there are only 5 items below the current scroll position but this is not so.

Rather As soon as the first set of items are loaded from the API, another is sent (without scrolling), received and parsed . After which yet another request is sent (still without scrolling) and parsed. This process continues (without scrolling) until the app is exited.

**My RecyclerView**

```
 mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
 recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new FadeInLeftAnimator());
 recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
 adapter = new PostAdapter(mPostItemList, getActivity());
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener( mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(final int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onLoadMore called");
                morePostsUrl = postUrl + "&page=" + page;
                getMorePostArray(morePostsUrl, true, false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the problem is that the RecyclerView has a NestedScrollView as a parent. When I removed the NestedScrollView, this problem stopped.

Comment: Thanks I spent 3 hour for this but u save my extra hours but I didn't get It why RecyclerView scroll endless without scroll in nestedScrollview can u explain ? I need recycle view inside scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this is a problem if you have a `<ScrollView>` in your layout (not only `NestedScrollView`).

Removing the `ScrollView` solved the problem for me!

Btw: This was only a problem when testing on older phones...

Tested with Samsung Galaxy S3 -> You must remove the `ScrollView`
Tested with Samsung Galaxy S8 -> Works fine with `ScrollView`