# Android: load data from web service to recyclerview

Tags: android, web-services, android-recyclerview

I have been working for a while now with `cardview` and `recyclerview` but I still have doubts about a real situation. In all the examples that I have gone through people uses a simple array as a source of pictures and text that they already have in `drawable` folder to fill up the cards, so the data is like pre-defined.

But how does it work in a real situation where your data (like a products catalog) is in a web service and it can be like millions of products?

Maybe you go for the solution of sending a Volley request and load a "chunck" of items (pics and text) each time?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement endless list with RecyclerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)

Comment: i believe that question is focused in getting the end of the list but not in how to get items from web service to recyclerview which is my point here.

Comment: try searching for keyword `pagination` ,if you look at the answer to the question you can sent your request for a page of items in the mentioned line,but for that your web service should support pagination

Comment: thanks man!, it can be a good start!