# How to implement pagination with recyclerview via api url indexing

Tags: java, android, rest, android-recyclerview, pagination

I know the title seems weird, but basically what I want is to apply pagination to my list and control it using the url api endpoint as a parameter.!

so the endpoint looks like this for example > `www.someapi.com/josn/list?pageIndex=1`

and it will give a response with array of 10 items, and if I want more I have to change the index of the parameter to 2 and so on.!

response

```
{
    "Succeeded": true,
    "AvailableChallenge": true,
    "DebugError": "",
    "NextPage": 2,
    "AllPages": 2,
    "Challenges": [
        {
            "ID": 114,
            "Title": "Amet sit id ratione dolorem numquam"
        },
        {
            "ID": 114,
            "Title": "Amet sit id ratione dolorem numquam"
        }
        ...
        ..
        .
        ]
 }
```

I tied everything, but couldn't get it done correctly, I have tried most of the solutions in **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)** and no luck.
I've also tried to use these two library **[Paginate](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate)** & **[recyclerview-paginated](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/recyclerview-paginated)** and even this **[SuperRecyclerView](https://github.com/Malinskiy/SuperRecyclerView)**. but it didn't work.!

Any help with the best logic for controlling this will help a lot.

---

**Code for [SuperRecyclerView](https://github.com/Malinskiy/SuperRecyclerView)**

```
public class ChallengesListFragment extends BaseFragment {

  private int pageNumber = 1; 
  private SuperRecyclerView recyclerview;
  private ArrayList<ChallengeActive> data;
  private ChallengesAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_challenges_list, container, false);
    initView(rootView);
    initRecycler();
    getData(1);
    return rootView;
  }

 private void initRecycler() {
    data = new ArrayList<>();
  
    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    adapter = new ChallengesAdapter(data, getActivity(), this); 
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerview.setupMoreListener(new OnMoreListener() {
      @Override
      public void onMoreAsked(int overallItemsCount, int itemsBeforeMore, int maxLastVisiblePosition) {
 
        pageNumber++;
        getData(maxLastVisiblePosition);
      }
    }, 10);

    recyclerview.setRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh() {
        pageNumber = 1;
        getData(pageNumber);
      }
    });
   
  }
 
  private void getData(final int pageNumber) {

      WebRequests.GetActiveChallenges(pageNumber, new onResult() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Object object) {
        ArrayList<ChallengeActive> list = (ArrayList<ChallengeActive>) object;
        data.clear();
        data.addAll(list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
      }

      @Override
      public void onFail(Object object) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, try again later",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      }
    }); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: add your code..

Comment: I've tried a bunch of ways... I'll post some.

Comment: Question: the list of data from next paginated answer from the server, you want to add it to the existing one or replace it ?

Comment: Could you add an example of the API response? Do you have any ownership above this API so that in case you want to, you could change the response model?

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan well, I think adding it better ux. since all items won't be too big anyway.

Comment: see code added guys.

Comment: @anthonymonori I don't think I can, since the same api is already implemented in the ios version of the app. so I can change the model. but I will post the response for u to see it.

Comment: @pskink any example for api request, the site gives a db example.

Comment: 1-on recycle scroll add new response to `data` list.  2-notifyDataChange to recycleView adapter. 3-have fun.

Comment: @Ibrahim can you post an answer with an example?

Comment: It's not much different comparing with @lonut answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I did it using **[Paginate Library](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate)**

---

**The Code**

```
public class ChallengesListFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnRefreshListener, Paginate.Callbacks { 

// other variables..
  private int currentPage = 1;
  private boolean hasMore;
  private boolean loadingInProgress;


  @RequiresApi(api = VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_challenges_list, container, false);
    initView(rootView);
    initToolbar();
    initRecycler();
    getData();

    return rootView;
  }

  private void initRecycler() {
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    adapter = new ChallengesAdapter(data, getActivity(), this);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);

    Paginate.with(recyclerview, this)
        .setLoadingTriggerThreshold(3)
        .addLoadingListItem(false)
        .build();
  }

  private void getData() {

     swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
    WebRequests.GetActiveChallenges(currentPage, new onResult() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Object object) {

        ArrayList<Challenge> list = (ArrayList<Challenge>) object;
        data.addAll(list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (list.size() == 10) {
          currentPage++;
          hasMore = true;
        } else {
          hasMore = false;
        }
        loadingInProgress = false;
        swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);


      }

      @Override
      public void onFail(Object object) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, try again later",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

      }
    });

  } 

  public ChallengesListFragment() {
   } 

  @Override
  public void onRefresh() {
    currentPage = 1;
    loadingInProgress = true;
    getData();
   }

  @Override
  public void onLoadMore() {
    loadingInProgress = true;
     Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable hintRunnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        getData();
      }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(hintRunnable, 1500);

  }

  @Override
  public boolean isLoading() {
    return loadingInProgress;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasLoadedAllItems() {
    return !hasMore;
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in a project... In this case I add more elements when bottom of the list is reached

```
rv_flohtainer_events.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (!rv_flohtainer_events.canScrollVertically(1)){
                if (!(eventsResponse.getCurrent_page() == eventsResponse.getLast_page())) {
                    pageEventsRequest++;
                    makeVendorEventsRequest();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The request I do is with retrofit, and it looks like this

```
@GET(RestClient.API_EVENTS_URL)
Call<EventsResponse> getEvents(@Query("page") int page)
```

Comment: I have a question: Why do you call `getData(maxLastVisiblePosition);` ? I suppose `maxLastVisiblePosition` is 10 or something... Also, `onSuccess()` method you do `data.clear();  data.addAll(list);` of course you will have only 10 elements(but they are changing?)

Comment: I thought it was responsible for the pages count.! but you are right about `data.clear()`I shouldn't clear the data if I want to add the next 10 items to the original ones. But I solved my problem after a lot of search with `Paginate` Library. I post the solution in a new answer in a moment, so thanks anyway man for the help.