# How to signal an Observable to produce more data

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Is there any way to signal an Observable to produce more data?

I have a buffered Observable that produces 10 items and i want it to continue producing more items only when i want to.

To be more specific, i have an infinite scrolling Recycler View, i want to produce more items only when i continue scrolling to the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview this is the main idea, simply add your logic to the `onScrolled` event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement endless list with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already some sort of a back-pressured data source.

You can use [request(n)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Subscriber.html#request-long-) to let your data source know that you are ready for more items.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have an Observer that emits page scrool events, let's call it paginator.

On each emission you can switch to another observer that brings more data,

```
            paginator
                    .onBackpressureDrop()
                    .map { lastVisibleIndex -> (lastVisibleIndex + 2) / PAGE_SIZE + 1 }
                    .distinct()
                    .concatMap { page -> getCollectionsObservable(page, pageSize)
                    }
                    .subscribeWith(GetCollectionObserver())
    )
}
```