# Is there any way I can fetch 50 items a time and then fetch next 50 and on-wards?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am fetching 1000 items from server at a time and displaying it in Recycler view.
Is there any way I can fetch 50 items a time from server and then fetch next 50 from server and then on-wards from server as well?
If not possible, then how can I display only 50 item in recycler view at first and then respective on load more button click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement endless list with RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. it's called "Pagination of data", you can use `OnScrollListener` for `RecyclerView` and load more data from there.

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library - do not use any custom `OnScrollListener`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Api should build in a way that it can process according LIMIT and OFFSET

server side query will be like....
SELECT contact_id, last_name, first_name
FROM contacts
ORDER BY contact_id DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 2;

Comment: than you can hit api onScrollListener at end index, getting 1000 data may slow down the app

Comment: that's the answer i was looking for -kuber singh ji

Answer (score 0):

you should select the first 50 items and after selecting generate a token for next item to next 50 item