# Android Expandable listview load new data pagination

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

How to detect scroll reaches bottom expandable listview and load new data when scroll reaches bottom

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview ?

Comment: it is recyclerview scroll . i am looking for expandable list view scroll reaches bottom detect