# RecyclerView scrolling to bottom of page doesn't trigger .addOnScrollListener's canScrollVertically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a skipping feature in my vertical recyclerview. When a user clicks a button, the recyclerView will scroll all the way to the bottom and trigger an API call. Right now to check if the user is at the bottom of the screen, I am using `.addOnScrollListener` on my recyclerview.

```
mGridRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                //SCROLL_STATE_IDE prevents repeated calls from happening
                // when near bottom of screen and slightly scroll up a bit
                if(!mGridRecycler.canScrollVertically(1) && newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: CALLED WTF");
                    mActivity.getNextPageGridView();
                }
            }
        });
```

And to implement the skipping feature to the last item, I am using this method on a button:

```
mGridRecycler.scrollToPosition(mList.size() - 1);
```

It skips to the last item, however the API call is not triggered because the `if-statement` is not called. Anyone know what I can make it work successfully?

Comment: I did not understand is the api call not working or the if condition inside of the onScrollStateChanged is always false?

Comment: The if condition is not called even though I am skipping to the bottom of the page and can not scroll anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643292/12546733

Comment: If scroll manually to the bottom, does the API call works?

Comment: @harrytmthy Yes it does. Only when trying to skip to the bottom of the page doing it programmatically, it doesn't work

Comment: @davids. Good. Can you update your question and show me your `if-statement` which triggers the API call? I am really sure that is the problem.

Comment: @davids. Please add XML layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecyclerView does not know how LayoutManager will handle the scroll.
You'll only receive a call to `onScrolled` if *first* and or *last* child position changes after a layout, you're not gonna get `onScrollStateChanged` callback.

**What should you do?**

Alternatively you can use `smoothScrollToPosition(..)` method, **OR** override `onScrolled` method, **OR** make a request to your API right after the *skip button* click, which is the best solution for your scenario.

Comment: I changed it to ```.smoothScrollToPosition``` and the API call is now working when I skip. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

It will not scroll to the end of your layout if your content layout had a top margin or your item view have margin. I don't remember exactly but try to remove all margin of `itemview` and `contentview`. I solved the problem with a little hack, adding an empty view to the end of the LinearLayout earlier in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Recylerview scrolling is very fast so try to give a delay of 1 sec using handler or you can also use

```
recyclerView.post(() -> mGridRecycler.scrollToPosition(mList.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In order to properly implement an auto smooth scrolling you need to do the following:**

Declare a scroll speed constant:

```
companion object {
    const val SMOOTH_SCROLL_SPEED = 100f
}
```

Create a global SmoothScroller param:

```
private lateinit var smoothScroller: SmoothScroller
```

In your init method: Initialize the SmoothScroller object:

```
smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
    override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
        return SNAP_TO_START
    }

    override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics?): Float {
        displayMetrics?.let {
            return SMOOTH_SCROLL_SPEED / it.densityDpi
        }
        return super.calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

Create this method and call it whenever you wish to smoothScroll to any position in the list:

```
open fun smoothScroll(position: Int) {
    smoothScroller.targetPosition = position
    yourRecycleView.layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
}
```