# Kotlin paginate API data with volley

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, android-volley

I have following api call function and I'd like to know how can I make pagination for my data?

#### Logic

1. Receiving data from API (done)
2. Printing data into recyclerview (done)
3. Making data paginate (either **by scroll** or **by page numbers** `doesn't make any difference for me`)

#### Questions

1. How to make my data paginate?
2. Is it best if I return data paginated by back-end or make them paginate in my app?

#### Current behavior

Currently my data are fully returned by data (without pagination) so if I have 1 item or 1000 items they all will be available at the same time (code below)

`Code`

```
private fun getProjects() {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val url = "https://example.com/api/projects"

    val stringReq : StringRequest =
        object : StringRequest(
            Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                val projects = Gson().fromJson(response, Projects::class.java)

                defText.isVisible = false
                total_projects_text = projects.total
                (activity as MainActivity?)?.setActionBarTitle("Projects ($total_projects_text)")

                // showing recyclerview data
                projectsRecycler.isVisible = true
                projectsRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                    context,
                    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                    false
                )
                projectsRecycler.adapter = ProjectAdapter(context, projects)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                defText.isVisible = true
            }
        ){
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                return headers
            }
        }
    queue.add(stringReq)
}
```

Comment: How will make them paginate in app will help that's defeats the whole of pagination . Its the bytes of data travel on HTTP we are optimizing by using pagination . Your API should serve data by page and you need add UI logic for it call the next page when u reached at end of List . So first Your API need to be paged later you can add pagination to RecyclerView Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview.

Comment: @ADM so what you suggest is that I make my data paginated by server side right? and about `you need add UI logic for it call the next page when u reached at end of List` part can you give an example? (I've never done pagination before in android :D)

Comment: your answers are a simple search away if you want to do paging [paging library for android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)