# How to add, prepend and append value in MutableStateFlow in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Hey I am new in Kotlin Flow. I am using **MutableStateFlow** to add value, append value, prepend value in flow.

**1.** I am trying to use `println()` after `collectLatest` it's not printing anything. Can someone explain me why this is not working.

**2.** Can someone guide me how to `add`,`append` and `prepend` list in flow.

**For example**

**Append**

my flow list value is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and want to add `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

**Output** will be

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

**Prepend**

The same list of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` after **append**. I want to do **prepend** in the list and the value is `[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]`.

**Output** will be

`[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I am trying but I don't understand why this function is not working.

**Main.kt**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow<List<Int>>(emptyList())
    val updateList = listOf<Int>(-5, -4, -3, -2, -1)

    for (i in 1..10) {
        flow.value += i
    }

    flow.collectLatest {
        println(it)
    }

    println("After Update")
    flow.value = flow.value + updateList

    flow.collectLatest {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not include pictures of code. Please include the actual text of the code.

Comment: Hey @Tenfour04 thanks for guiding me. I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SharedFlow or StateFlow has no end unless it's cancelled. Calling `collect` or `collectLatest` on it is sort of like creating a `while(true)` loop. It will never finish iterating because it's always possible it will have another value emitted.

In [the documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) you can read about it in the section that starts with"**Shared flow never completes.**".

Comment: can you guide me how to add,prepend list value in mutableStateFlow?

Comment: The way you're doing it is fine. You just can't do it in the same coroutine that is collecting it. Any code after a `collect` call will never be reached. If you want to collect a single value and then continue in the coroutine, you can use `first` instead of `collect`.

Comment: can you give me example please?

Comment: Replace `collectLatest` with `first` or `first().let`, basically. But in an actual app you would not be emitting to a flow and collecting from it in the same coroutine.

Comment: Got it @Tenfour04 thanks a million. I am leaning basic because I need to implement this in my android application. But I don't understand why this is not working in my android application. Can you please guide me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70699636/11560810)