# How to prepend list in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Hey I want to prepend item in list in kotlin. I am trying to add item but unfortunately, I am getting error, can someone guide me how to do that.

```
val prepareMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<ConversationCount>> = MutableLiveData(
            emptyList()
        )

fun formatData() {
        val conversationCount = mutableListOf<ConversationCount>()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dateRange.forEachIndexed { index, dateRangeValue ->
                val findData = data?.find {
                    dateRangeValue == it.dateObject
                }
                conversationCount.add(
                    ConversationCount(
                        setDay(dateRangeValue),
                        index,
                        findData != null
                    )
                )
            }
            prepareMutableLiveData.value = mutableListOf(conversationCount) + prepareMutableLiveData.value
        }
    }
```

I am getting error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ConversationCount
Found:
List<ConversationCount>?
Type mismatch.
Required:
List<ConversationCount>?
Found:
List<List<ConversationCount>?>
Type mismatch.
Required:
ConversationCount
Found:
MutableList<ConversationCount
```

[image]

I tried this

```
prepareMutableLiveData.value = conversationCount + prepareMutableLiveData.value
```

**it gives error**

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ConversationCount
Found:
List<ConversationCount>
```

Comment: `conversationCount` is already a List . So you can simply use `prepareMutableLiveData.value = conversationCount + prepareMutableLiveData.value`. See if that works .. may be some casting required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `conversationCount` is already a List and your live data is also a list i.e `MutableLiveData<List<ConversationCount>>` you can simply use the code below .

```
prepareMutableLiveData.value = conversationCount + prepareMutableLiveData.value.orEmpty()
```

`orEmpty()` here is for null safety . you can also use `!!` but its not safe.

Comment: can you look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70699636/11560810)